# How to detect via Java whether a particular process is running under Windows?

Tags: java

Well the title pretty much sums the question. The only thing I found is [this](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0593.html)
but I'm not sure if thats the way to go.

Comment: Ambiguous question.  Do you want to figure out if the Windows process is a java app, or do you want to figure out how a Java app can tell if it is running on Windows?

Comment: What do you have to work with? A process ID? The name of the executable? Did you start the process? Are you waiting to see if it finished yet? Basically why do you want to check if it's running. There are different techniques depending on the situation.

Comment: @Stephen C you are completely right, I wasn't clear enough! I want to know how to programmatically see if for example notepad.exe is running or if firefox.exe is running etc... hope that clears it out :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the wmic utility to check the list of running processes.
Suppose you want to check if the windows' explorer.exe process is running :

```
String line;
try {
    Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wmic.exe");
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
    OutputStreamWriter oStream = new OutputStreamWriter(proc.getOutputStream());
    oStream .write("process where name='explorer.exe'");
    oStream .flush();
    oStream .close();
    while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    input.close();
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace();
}
```

See http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html or http://support.microsoft.com/servicedesks/webcasts/wc072402/listofsampleusage.asp for some example of what you can get from wmic...

**2022 update**

As you can see in the link above, wmic was deprecated in Windows 10. The good news is that now the `ps` command works on windows 10 under powershell, so you can get your "cross-platform" support with something like this (untested):

```
public class ProcessInfo {

    static boolean isProcessRunning(String processName) {
        String[] command = new String[]{ "powershell", "ps", processName };
        try {
            if (System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().contains("linux")) {
                command = new String[]{ "ps", "-o", "comm" };
            }
            Process ps = new ProcessBuilder(command).start();
            return new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(ps.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
            ).lines().anyMatch(line -> line.contains(processName));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(String.join(" ", command) + ": No such command on this OS.");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, as i said in my comment early I wasn't clear enough. :)

Comment: Is it possible to then work out how to kill a running process from the windows handle id?

Comment: Thanks for the nice example. Is there though any way to handle this issue platform independently? I need this functionality under Linux and Apple as well.

Comment: It's 2022... windows 10 now has a ps command! Answer updated.

Answer (score 2):

os.name should do it. More information [here](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html)

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you need to know it for!

Most information can be derived from the default runtime properties, without actually checking the operating system properties.

Have a look at what http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties() provides:

```
java.version    Java Runtime Environment version
java.vendor Java Runtime Environment vendor
java.vendor.url Java vendor URL
java.home   Java installation directory
java.vm.specification.version   Java Virtual Machine specification version
java.vm.specification.vendor    Java Virtual Machine specification vendor
java.vm.specification.name  Java Virtual Machine specification name
java.vm.version Java Virtual Machine implementation version
java.vm.vendor  Java Virtual Machine implementation vendor
java.vm.name    Java Virtual Machine implementation name
java.specification.version  Java Runtime Environment specification version
java.specification.vendor   Java Runtime Environment specification vendor
java.specification.name Java Runtime Environment specification name
java.class.version  Java class format version number
java.class.path Java class path
java.library.path   List of paths to search when loading libraries
java.io.tmpdir  Default temp file path
java.compiler   Name of JIT compiler to use
java.ext.dirs   Path of extension directory or directories
os.name Operating system name
os.arch Operating system architecture
os.version  Operating system version
file.separator  File separator ("/" on UNIX)
path.separator  Path separator (":" on UNIX)
line.separator  Line separator ("\n" on UNIX)
user.name   User's account name
user.home   User's home directory
user.dir    User's current working directory
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to determine if a process you created is still running?

1. If you have the PID the link you posted will do.
2. If the other process is also your own (your code), you can make it get exclusive lock on a file; try locking it from the other code if it succeeds the other process is not running.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried in non Windows based systems.
perhaps the PID divisibility by 4 will provide a clue
More info on this PID propery here : [About the pid of the process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822797/about-the-pid-of-the-process/822826)

and here
http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2008/02/28/7925962.aspx