# Check if process is java process in Windows

Tags: java, windows, winapi, process

How to check if a process, given the process id, is a legitimate Java application process on Windows. Legitimate, meaning an instance of a JVM that might not be the `java.exe` process from the standard java installation e.g. bundled `java.exe` from installations like IntelliJ IDEA. Some of these JVMs might not even be Oracle JVMs, but OpenJDK or IBM versions. But for simplicity's sake, let's assume Oracle JVMs.

I have tried getting the CommandLine of the process and checking if the first argument ends with `java.exe` or `javaw.exe`, but the issue is that this can be faked a process that also happens to be called `java.exe` but is not an instance of the JVM.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect via Java whether a particular process is running under Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318220/how-to-detect-via-java-whether-a-particular-process-is-running-under-windows)

Comment: Short: You can't, at least reliably.