# How to 'grep' a continuous stream?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep, tail

Is that possible to use `grep` on a continuous stream?

What I mean is sort of a `tail -f <file>` command, but with `grep` on the output in order to keep only the lines that interest me.

I've tried `tail -f <file> | grep pattern` but it seems that `grep` can only be executed once `tail` finishes, that is to say never.

Comment: It is highly likely the program generating the file is not flushing its output.

Comment: `tail -f file` works (I see the new output in real time)

Comment: Would be appropriate to http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Luc indeed, didn't think of that

Comment: May be there is no new lines in your input stream? If so grep will not proceed.

Comment: This is a FAQ: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/009

Comment: hehe, buffering in pipelines! maybe [these answers](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/182242/38371) would be of help to somebody googling this topic here

Comment: @Lynch I encountered the problem you mentioned when grep from a super slow (sleep infinity) steamed log, and the string I greped is right before the sleep command, therefore no new line is streamed, and it's never exit. Can you give some hint?

Comment: @Psyduck If I understand correctly the problem is the buffer never being flushed in your case. I did not test it but may be `unbuffer` could help: https://linux.die.net/man/1/unbuffer

Answer (score 1537, accepted):

Turn on `grep`'s line buffering mode when using BSD grep (FreeBSD, Mac OS X etc.)

```
tail -f file | grep --line-buffered my_pattern
```

It looks like a while ago `--line-buffered` didn't matter for GNU grep (used on pretty much any Linux) as it flushed by default (YMMV for other Unix-likes such as SmartOS, AIX or QNX). However, as of November 2020, `--line-buffered` is needed (at least with GNU grep 3.5 in openSUSE, but it seems generally needed based on comments below).

Comment: what happens if I tail a log file that gets rotated, while this is running? Will logrotate be able to rotate the file?

Comment: @MichaelNiemand you could use tail -F file | grep --line-buffered my_pattern

Comment: and make sure to take out your usual flags that you don't want like -r (for other dunces out there)

Comment: @MichaelGoldshteyn Take it easy. People upvote it because they find this page when they google "grep line buffered" and it solves a problem for them which may not exactly be the one posed as the question.

Comment: @MichaelGoldshteyn it appears to be true in certain situations. For example, I'm executing the command remotely in an automatic `ssh` session (specifying the command in the arguments). Do you have a more complete explanation? thanks!

Comment: @MichaelGoldshteyn — I suspect the issue here is that people confirm that it gives the correct output by running the command themselves, and then upvote it, not realizing that the "--line-buffered" part is completely superfluous.

Comment: I came here trying to grep the output of `strace`. Without the `--line-buffered`, it won't work.

Comment: @MichaelGoldshteyn (and the upvoters of his comment): I have always had this problem with `tail -f | grep`, and `--line-buffered` solves it for me (on Ubuntu 14.04, GNU grep version 2.16). Where is the "use line buffering if stdout is a tty" logic implemented? In http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/src/grep.c, `line_buffered` is set only by the argument parser.

Comment: I don't think --line-bufferred is the default option, at least not on ssh connections.  I've always had this problem and never new about ---line-bufferred until today... works great!

Comment: @MichaelGoldshteyn I'm on macOS using BSD grep and without `--line-buffered` I get no output. However, after testing, it looks like GNU grep does what you describe. So like most things Unix, it depends on your platform's implementation. Since the question did not specify platform, **your** information appears to be false - after reviewing the code for BSD grep and comparing it to GNU grep, the behavior is definitely controlled by the --line-buffered option. It's just that only GNU grep flushes by default.

Answer (score 135):

I use the `tail -f <file> | grep <pattern>` all the time.

It will wait till grep flushes, not till it finishes (I'm using Ubuntu).

Comment: Which can last quite a while, so try not to get impatient.

Comment: How long can it take approximately?

Comment: @Matthieu: Depends mainly on what you grep for, and how large the buffers are on your OS. If the grep only matches a short string every few hours, it will be days before the first flush.

Comment: Tail doesn't use output buffering - grep does.

Comment: No, grep does not do output buffering when the output is going to a tty device, as it clearly is in this answer. It does line buffering! This is the correct answer and should be the accepted answer. See my longer comment to the currently accepted (**wrong**) answer for more details.

Comment: This the solution which worked for me in Git Bash on Windows. (Deleted my similar answer below which included the optional `-` for grep, un-needed.)

Comment: @MichaelGoldshteyn as pointed out multiple times in reply to your longer answer your information only applies to GNU grep, not BSD or other implementations, so can you check your aggression and cock-suredness hey?

Answer (score 86):

I think that your problem is that grep uses some output buffering. Try

```
tail -f file | stdbuf -o0 grep my_pattern
```

it will set output buffering mode of grep to unbuffered.

Comment: And this has the advantage that it can be used for many other commands besides `grep`.

Comment: However, as I've discovered after playing more with it, some commands only flush their output when connected to a tty, and for that, `unbuffer` (in the `expect-dev` package on debian) is *king*. So I'd use unbuffer over stdbuf.

Comment: @Peter V. Mørch Yes, you are right, unbuffer can sometimes work where stdbuf can't. But I think you are trying to find a 'magic' programm that will always fix your problems instead of understanding your problem. Creating a virtual tty is unrelated task. Stdbuf does exactly what we want (sets standard output buffer to give value), while unbuffer does a lot of hidden stuff that we may not want (compare interactive `top` with stdbuf and unbuffer). And there is really no 'magic' solution: unbuffer fails sometimes too, for example awk uses different buffer implementation (stdbuf will fail too).

Comment: "But I think you are trying to find a 'magic' programm that will 
always fix your problems instead of understanding your problem." - I think you're right! ;-)

Comment: Some more info about `stdbuf`, `unbuffer, and stdio buffering at http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/

Comment: @PeterV.Mørch   "But I think you are trying to find a 'magic'  ... Aren't we all ;-? Good luck to all.

Comment: This was really useful as I am using a busy box version of grep which does not have the usual line buffered option. Got lucky scrolling down for more answers 

Answer (score 23):

If you want to find matches in the *entire* file (not just the tail), and you want it to sit and wait for any new matches, this works nicely:

```
tail -c +0 -f <file> | grep --line-buffered <pattern>
```

The `-c +0` flag says that the output should start `0` bytes (`-c`) from the beginning (`+`) of the file.

Answer (score 17):

In most cases, you can `tail -f /var/log/some.log |grep foo` and it will work just fine.

If you need to use multiple greps on a running log file and you find that you get no output, you may need to stick the `--line-buffered` switch into your **middle** grep(s), like so:

```
tail -f /var/log/some.log | grep --line-buffered foo | grep bar
```

Answer (score 12):

you may consider this answer as enhancement .. usually I am using

```
tail -F <fileName> | grep --line-buffered  <pattern> -A 3 -B 5
```

-F is better in case of file rotate (-f will not work properly  if file rotated)

-A and -B is useful to get lines just before and after the pattern occurrence .. these blocks will appeared between dashed line separators

But For me I prefer doing the following

```
tail -F <file> | less
```

this is very useful if you want to search inside streamed logs. I mean go back and forward and look deeply

Comment: `grep -C 3 <pattern>`, replaces -A <N> and -B <N> if N is same.

Answer (score 7):

Didn't see anyone offer my usual go-to for this:

```
less +F <file>
ctrl + c
/<search term>
<enter>
shift + f
```

I prefer this, because you can use `ctrl + c` to stop and navigate through the file whenever, and then just hit `shift + f` to return to the live, streaming search.

Answer (score 4):

**sed** would be a better choice (*stream* editor)

`tail -n0 -f <file> | sed -n '/search string/p'`

and then if you wanted the tail command to exit once you found a particular string:

`tail --pid=$(($BASHPID+1)) -n0 -f <file> | sed -n '/search string/{p; q}'`

Obviously a bashism: $BASHPID will be the process id of the tail command.  The sed command is next after tail in the pipe, so the sed process id will be $BASHPID+1.

Comment: The assumption that the next process started on the system (`$BASHPID+1`) will be yours is false in many situations, and this does nothing to solve the buffering problem which is probably what the OP was trying to ask about.  In particular, recommending `sed` over `grep` here seems like merely a matter of (dubious) preference. (You can get `p;q` behavior with `grep -m 1` if that's the point you are attempting to deliver.)

Comment: Works, the sed command prints each lines as soon as there are ready, the grep command with `--line-buffered` did not. I sincerely do not understand the minus 1.

Comment: It is heretofore established that buffering is the problem with **grep**.  No special action is required to handle line buffering using **sed**, it is default behavior, hence my emphasis of the word _stream_.  And true, there is no _guarantee_ $BASHPID+1 will be the correct **pid** to follow, but since pid allocation [is sequential](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446727/how-does-linux-determine-the-next-pid#answer-3457108) and the piped command is assigned a **pid** immediately following, it is utterly probable.

Answer (score 4):

Coming some late on this question, considering this kind of work as an important part of monitoring job, here is my *(not so short)* answer...

## Following logs using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)

### 1. Command `tail`

This command is a little more porewfull than read on already published answer

1. Difference between *follow* option `tail -f` and `tail -F`, from *manpage*:

   > ```
   >    -f, --follow[={name|descriptor}]
   >           output appended data as the file grows;
   > ...
   >    -F     same as --follow=name --retry
   > ...
   >    --retry
   >           keep trying to open a file if it is inaccessible
   > ```

   This mean: by using `-F` instead of `-f`, `tail` will re-open file(s) when removed (on log rotation, for sample).
   This is usefull for watching logfile over many days.
2. Ability of following *more than one file* simultaneously
   I've already used:

   ```
   tail -F /var/www/clients/client*/web*/log/{error,access}.log /var/log/{mail,auth}.log \
              /var/log/apache2/{,ssl_,other_vhosts_}access.log \
              /var/log/pure-ftpd/transfer.log
   ```

   For following events through hundreds of files... (consider rest of this answer to understand how to make it readable... ;)
3. Using switches `-n` (Don't use `-c` for line buffering!).
   By default `tail` will show 10 last lines. This can be tunned:

   ```
   tail -n 0 -F file
   ```

   Will follow file, but only new lines will be printed

   ```
   tail -n +0 -F file
   ```

   Will print **whole** file before following his progression.

### 2. Buffer issues when *piping*:

If you plan to filter ouptuts, consider *buffering*! See `-u` option for `sed`, `--line-buffered` for `grep`, or `stdbuf` command:

```
tail -F /some/files | sed -une '/Regular Expression/p'
```

Is (a lot more efficient than using `grep`) a lot more reactive than if you does'nt use `-u` switch in `sed` command.

```
tail -F /some/files |
    sed -une '/Regular Expression/p' |
    stdbuf -i0 -o0 tee /some/resultfile
```

### 3. Recent journaling system

On recent system, instead of `tail -f /var/log/syslog` you have to run `journalctl -xf`, in near same way...

```
journalctl -axf | sed -une '/Regular Expression/p'
```

But read `man page`, this tool was built for log analyses!

### 4. Integrating this in a [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) script

1. Colored output of two files (or more)

   Here is a sample of script watching for many files, coloring ouptut differently for 1st file than others:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   tail -F "$@" |
       sed -une "
           /^==> /{h;};
           //!{
               G;
               s/^\\(.*\\)\\n==>.*${1//\//\\\/}.*<==/\\o33[47m\\1\\o33[0m/;
               s/^\\(.*\\)\\n==> .* <==/\\o33[47;31m\\1\\o33[0m/;
               p;}"
   ```

   They work fine on my host, running:

   ```
   sudo ./myColoredTail /var/log/{kern.,sys}log
   ```
2. Interactive script

   You may be watching logs for reacting on events?

   Here is a little script playing some sound when some USB device appear or disappear, but same script could send mail, or any other interaction, like powering on coffe machine...

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   exec {tailF}< <(tail -F /var/log/kern.log)
   tailPid=$!

   while :;do
       read -rsn 1 -t .3 keyboard
       [ "${keyboard,}" = "q" ] && break
       if read -ru $tailF -t 0 _ ;then
           read -ru $tailF line
           case $line in
               *New\ USB\ device\ found* ) play /some/sound.ogg ;;
               *USB\ disconnect* ) play /some/othersound.ogg ;;
           esac
           printf "\r%s\e[K" "$line"
       fi
   done

   echo
   exec {tailF}<&-
   kill $tailPid
   ```

   You could ***quit*** by pressing <kbd>Q</kbd> key.

Comment: Excellent and exhaustive answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this will actually work just fine. `Grep` and most Unix commands operate on streams one line at a time. Each line that comes out of tail will be analyzed and passed on if it matches.

Comment: That's not actually correct. If `grep` is the last command in the pipe chain, it will act as you explain. However, if it's in the middle it will buffer around 8k output at a time.

Answer (score 2):

This one command workes for me (Suse):

```
mail-srv:/var/log # tail -f /var/log/mail.info |grep --line-buffered LOGIN  >> logins_to_mail
```

collecting logins to mail service

Answer (score -2):

you certainly won't succeed with

```
tail -f /var/log/foo.log |grep --line-buffered string2search
```

when you use "colortail" as an alias for tail, eg. in bash

```
alias tail='colortail -n 30'
```

you can check by
    type alias
if this outputs something like
    tail isan alias of `colortail -n 30`.
then you have your culprit :)

Solution:

remove the alias with

```
unalias tail
```

ensure that you're using the 'real' tail binary by this command

```
type tail
```

which should output something like:

```
tail is /usr/bin/tail
```

and then you can run your command

```
tail -f foo.log |grep --line-buffered something
```

Good luck.

Answer (score -4):

Use awk(another great bash utility) instead of grep where you dont have the line buffered option! It will continuously stream your data from tail.

this is how you use grep

```
tail -f <file> | grep pattern
```

This is how you would use awk

```
tail -f <file> | awk '/pattern/{print $0}'
```

Comment: This is not correct; Awk out of the box performs line buffering, just like most other standard Unix tools.  (Moreover, the `{print $0}` is redundant, as printing is the default action when a condition passes.)