# Implementing pipe in java, the second program does not output in time (ping | grep)

Tags: java, pipe

I'm writing an IRC bot which can execute several commands and output the result to IRC channel. These commands are connected using pipe which is implemented in java.

In most cases, it works fine. But when executing `ping 127.0.0.1 | grep -in ttl`, the `grep` program does not output in time: it only output in about every 38 seconds, see the screenshot below.

[image: java PipingTest screenshot 1]

It looks like somewhere is buffering the output. How to let the second program output in time?

### Sample code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class PipingTest
{
    static ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool (10);

    static class CommandRunner implements Runnable
    {
        ProcessBuilder pb;
        String program;
        Process process;
        boolean isPipingOut = false;
        CyclicBarrier barrier;
        CommandRunner previousCommand;
        CommandRunner nextCommand;
        public OutputStream out = null;
        public InputStream in = null;
        public InputStream err = null;
        public OutputStream nextOut = null;

        public CommandRunner (ProcessBuilder pb, boolean isPipingOut, CyclicBarrier barrier, CommandRunner previousCommand, CommandRunner nextCommand)
        {
            this.pb = pb;
            program = pb.command().get(0);
            this.isPipingOut = isPipingOut;
            this.barrier = barrier;
            this.previousCommand = previousCommand;
            if (previousCommand!=null)
                previousCommand.nextCommand = this;
            this.nextCommand = nextCommand;
            if (nextCommand!=null)
                nextCommand.previousCommand = this;
        }
        @Override
        public void run ()
        {
            System.out.println ("Command [" + program + "] thread ID = " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
            try
            {
                process = pb.start ();
                out = process.getOutputStream ();
                in = process.getInputStream ();
                err = process.getErrorStream ();

                if (! isPipingOut)
                {
                    System.out.println (program + ": Synchronizing with [" + previousCommand.program + "] ...");
                    barrier.await ();
                }
                if (isPipingOut)
                {
                    System.out.println (program + ": Synchronizing with [" + nextCommand.program + "] ...");
                    barrier.await ();
                    System.out.println ("ok, synchronized, now go piping");
                    executor.execute (new Pipe(in, nextCommand.out));
                }

                BufferedReader br = null;
                String line;
                if (! isPipingOut)
                {
                    System.out.println (program + ": Consuming the stdout...");
                    br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(in));
                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        System.out.println (line);
                    }
                    System.out.println (program + ": stdout consumed");
                }
                System.out.println (program + ": Consuming the stderr...");
                br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(err));
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    System.out.println (line);
                }
                System.out.println (program + ": stderr consumed");

                int rc = process.waitFor ();
                System.out.println (program + ": exited value " + rc);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    static class Pipe implements Runnable
    {
        public OutputStream out = null;
        public InputStream in = null;
        public Pipe (InputStream in, OutputStream out)
        {
            this.in = in;
            this.out = out;
        }
        @Override
        public void run ()
        {
            System.out.println ("Pipe thread ID = " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
            System.out.println ("Piping...");
            long nTotal = 0;
            int nRead = 0;
            try
            {
                byte[] small_buffer = new byte[32];
                while (-1 != (nRead = in.read(small_buffer)))
                {
                    out.write (small_buffer, 0, nRead);
                    nTotal += nRead;
                    out.flush ();   // let next command get piped data as soon as possible, does it work?
                    System.out.println (new java.sql.Time(System.currentTimeMillis()) + "    piped " + nRead + " bytes, total=" + nTotal);
                }
                System.out.println ("Total piped " + nTotal + " bytes");
                in.close ();
                out.flush ();
                out.close ();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    static class WatchDog implements Runnable
    {
        int timeout = 0;
        List<CommandRunner> commands;
        public WatchDog (int timeout, List<CommandRunner> commands)
        {
            this.timeout = timeout;
            this.commands = commands;
        }
        @Override
        public void run ()
        {
            System.out.println ("WatchDog thread ID = " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
            try
            {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep (timeout);
                System.out.println ("WatchDog timeout, killing commands...");
                for (CommandRunner command : commands)
                {
                    System.out.println ("Killing command " + command.pb.command().get(0));
                    command.process.destroy ();
                }
                executor.shutdown ();
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        ProcessBuilder pbCmd1, pbCmd2;
        pbCmd1 = new ProcessBuilder ("ping", "127.0.0.1");
        //pbCmd1 = new ProcessBuilder ("yes", "ttl=123");
        pbCmd2 = new ProcessBuilder ("grep", "-in", "--color=always", "ttl");
        //pbCmd1 = new ProcessBuilder ("cat", "/etc/passwd");
        //pbCmd2 = new ProcessBuilder ("grep", "-in", "--color=always", "root");
        CyclicBarrier barrier = new CyclicBarrier(2);

        List<CommandRunner> commands = new ArrayList<CommandRunner> ();
        CommandRunner cmd1 = new CommandRunner (pbCmd1, true, barrier, null, null);
        CommandRunner cmd2 = new CommandRunner (pbCmd2, false, barrier, cmd1, null);

        commands.add (cmd1);
        commands.add (cmd2);
        WatchDog watchdog = new WatchDog (90, commands);

        executor.execute (cmd1);
        executor.execute (cmd2);
        executor.execute (watchdog);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

grep is not flushing its output buffer on every line. You will see something similar if you run something like:

```
ping 127.0.0.1 | grep -in ttl | cat
```

You can fix this by running grep with the `--line-buffered` option:

```
ping 127.0.0.1 | grep --line-buffered -in ttl
```

or a more general solution with stdbuf:

```
ping 127.0.0.1 | stdbuf -o0 grep -in ttl
```

See also: [How to 'grep' a continuous stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161821/how-to-grep-a-continuous-stream)

Comment: Good to know the `--line-buffered` option. However, when executing `ping 127.0.0.1 | grep -in ttl` in shell (Fedora 19/20), it's output does not seems been buffered, why executing it in java needs the `--line-buffered` option?

Comment: Grep does not buffer output to the terminal. In java grep is buffering the output because the output is going to a pipe and not to the terminal. For Fedora, try `ping 127.0.0.1 | grep -in ttl | cat` (like in my answer) to see the buffering in action

Comment: Thanks. I tried `pbCmd2.redirectOutput (ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);` to let `grep` output to terminal, and YES, it does not buffering. `ping 127.0.0.1 | grep -in ttl | cat` act like piping in java. Thanks for your explanation and the helpful link.