# Tail -f + grep?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, grep, tail

Tail has the following options:

```
-f      The -f option causes tail to not stop when end of file is reached, but rather to wait for additional data to be appended to the
             input.  The -f option is ignored if the standard input is a pipe, but not if it is a FIFO.
```

I'd like to only grep for `something` in the tail output.

```
tail -f <FILE> | grep <SOMETHING>
```

Issue is it only run grep once and is done. No other output happens. How can I make grep run correctly with the `-f`?

Comment: I often do exactly what you're describing, and it works. The `grep` command doesn't terminate until the `tail -f` process terminates, but of course it doesn't produce any output until something containing the pattern is appended to the file.

Comment: I can confirm the same on several platforms. I've never had trouble using tail+grep exactly as described here. What platform are you having trouble on?

Comment: `Issue is it only run grep once and is done` no that's not right.

Comment: I don't think you'll hit it here, but be careful in longer piped chains with grep (especially used more than once) that it may defult to a block buffering and thus not produce any output for quite some time, unless you explicitly specify --line-buffered

Comment: Ah chaining was the issue! That fixed it @ChrisStratton

Answer (score 68):

You will find another SO Question helpful: [How to 'grep' a continuous stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161821/how-to-grep-a-continuous-stream/7162898#7162898)

Turn on grep's line buffering mode.

```
tail -f file | grep --line-buffered my_pattern
```

Answer (score 10):

If this is a logfile it may be rotated. It will then stop giving data. 
This will not stop if file is rotated.

```
tail --follow=name /var/log/syslog | grep "some data"
```