# Bash statement meaning

Tags: bash, grep

I'm working on a project, and it's being run by an autoscript. The script has the following line:

```
./executable ./dev | grep -i "GET.*index.*200" > ./dev/logs/log1
```

I have my code writing to stdout, but it never gets written to log1. If I change it though and remove the grep command, it writes just fine. Any help would be appreciated, as I seemingly don't understand grep as well as I should.

Comment: Nope, it isn't. Only stderr gets written there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to 'grep' a continuous stream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161821/how-to-grep-a-continuous-stream)

Comment: I'm assuming the output from your command actually matches that grep pattern?

Comment: it would be good to include some sample output from `executable` that you expect to match. Does the `executable` use colored output? That could throw off your grep. did you notice the option in grep for `--line-buffered` (or similar)? That might help too. Good luck.

Comment: have you tried using `>>` instead of `>`, or even `*>`

Answer (score 1):

You might try to redirect std output in your script "executable" using commands:

```
exec > ./dev/logs/log1
exec 2> ./dev/logs/errlog1
```

So, now not need to use ">" in the line

```
./executable ./dev | grep -i "GET.*index.*200"
```

Also I recommend you to use only absolute paths in scripts.

*ps. [offtop] I can't write comments yet (not enough reputation).*