# grep waits for more lines before printing

Tags: bash, grep

I put this command into bash, expecting it to print `FOO` and then wait for more input:

```
(echo FOO; cat) | grep FOO | cat
```

Instead it prints nothing, and waits until I press Ctrl+D before anything appears.

If I remove the `|cat` at the end, the issue goes away.

What is going on here? Is grep waiting for more lines, and only when piped to something else? Or is bash/cat waiting?

Comment: both `cat`s are unnecessary. Why would you think it is grep waiting when you have yourself said that the issue goes away when you remove the last cat ? The first cat is the problem, you haven't give it an argument so it is reading from STDIN.

Comment: I know, I simplified the issue before posting. Originally the last `cat` was an other grep command, and the `(echo FOO; cat)` was a `tail -f`. I suspect the grep is waiting because it does not seem to matter what I pipe it to, as long as it is piped to something. I also know that a command can tell whether it is piped somewhere or not. For example `grep` can print with colors on the command line, but without if piped somewhere.

Comment: I don't think the `cat`s can be "unnecessary" in a theroretical question like this.

Comment: grep doesn't wait, and piping `tail -f` into two greps would not wait for input unless the grep wasn't matching anything. Post your actual problem instead of this which is clearly caused by cat waiting.

Comment: @MichaelJaros How can't they , the command would work without them and won't with them ?

Comment: @JID: you're wrong.. I can reproduce the behaviour. check my answer. and regarding your second comment, I can also reproduce that. the second cat does make a difference.

Comment: @JID: I meant: The OP used the `cat`s to provide a minimal example of what they wanted to understand. So they are necessary to reproduce the problem. I agree that they are kind of pointless in production code.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath As i have said in the comment on your answer i misunderstood OPs problem and my comments were to address what i thought was the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first `cat` is waiting for input.

`grep`, for performance reasons, is reading in chunks, there's not enough input, so it just waits. This can be resolved by forcing it to read each line:

```
(echo FOO; cat) | grep --line-buffered FOO | cat
```

Comment: This still waits for more input though,so i am not wrong.Actually i'm going to admit that i misread the question and am completely wrong as Op wanted that behaviour :(

Comment: Of course it waits, and it will till stdin is closed.

Comment: Thanks! I think this is the same issue as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161821/how-to-grep-a-continuous-stream I also found some info [here](http://blog.jpalardy.com/posts/grep-and-output-buffering/) and [here](http://www.perkin.org.uk/posts/how-to-fix-stdio-buffering.html).

Comment: RIght @JID , it hangs indefinably , just like the original post.

Comment: @NullSoulException: and that's exactly what the OP wants. the *issue* was that grep didn't print anything though there was a matching line.

Comment: you are right , @Karoly Horvath ...