# Pipe into into file

Tags: linux, bash

I have a command `fatrace/fatrace -t | grep "/home/eric/test.txt"`, which runs fatrace and filters down the result by piping into grep.  What should I do if I want to run this as a daemon and output the result to a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can simply use `>` or `>>` in order to pipe output to a file:

This will replace the content of /tmp/myFile with the grep output:

```
fatrace/fatrace -t | grep "/home/eric/test.txt" > /tmp/myFile
```

And this will append the grep output to the file:

```
fatrace/fatrace -t | grep "/home/eric/test.txt" >> /tmp/myFile
```

Comment: That's what I thought... I ran `sudo fatrace/fatrace -t | grep "/home/eric/test.txt" >> ./monitor.txt &` but nothing gets appended to monitor.txt...

Comment: @etang It works, but due to buffering it's written in large blocks so it can take a while before you see the first line. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161821/how-to-grep-a-continuous-stream).