# getting two lines from shell

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I use

```
cmd | egrep 'ID|Value'
```

andget the following output on my command line:

```
    ID: 2
Value: 21
    ID: 1
Value: 25
    ID: 1
Value: 22
    ID: 3
Value: 56
    ID: 1
Value: 23
    ID: 2
Value: 50
    ID: 2
Value: 56
    ID: 3
Value: 11
    ID: 3
Value: 26
```

I would like to filter it by one special ID. But when I use:

```
egrep 'ID: 1|Value'
```

It will show the same output with just ID 1, but the Values of all IDs.

I already read about awk, sed and regex, but i can't find anything that would really help me, but I'm also not that deep into that.

Someone can suggest an idea, or tell me that it's the wrong way to approach it and I should do it differently and how?

Output as wanted:

```
    ID: 1
Value: 25
    ID: 1
Value: 22
    ID: 1
Value: 23
```

Comment: so you want to show the block containing `ID: 1` together with the following line containing `Value: 25`?

Comment: I added what i would like to get as an output

Answer (score 8):

Just tell `grep` to print the matching line together with the next one:

```
$ grep -A1 'ID: 1$' file
    ID: 1
Value: 25
    ID: 1
Value: 22
--
    ID: 1
Value: 23
```

From `man grep`:

> **-A NUM, --after-context=NUM**
>
> Print NUM  lines  of  trailing  context  after  matching  lines.
>   Places   a  line  containing  a  group  separator  (--)  between
>   contiguous groups of matches.  With the  -o  or  --only-matching
>   option, this has no effect and a warning is given.

Note the usage of `$` to mark the end of the line. Otherwise, this would match lines line `ID: 1323423423`.

If you don't like the `--` appearing in between matches, get rid of it with:

```
grep -A1 --no-group-separator 'ID: 1$' file
#        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Yep, that should suffice.

Comment: Note that -A1 means "After", if you wanted the line before you could use -B1 ("Before"

Comment: @Alan exactly. And if your "after" and "before" match, you can join them using `-C`.

Comment: seems that i didn't read the man as carefully as i thought.

It works fine, but my output is coming in blocks now...!?
it's like he collects enough input to print it in the screen. 
any ideas how to get more "realtime" output?

Comment: @DaPole not sure what you mean here. Are you grepping a continuous stream?

Comment: Yes, I'm grepping a continious stream of BLE data.

Comment: @DaPole then you need to use [`--line-buffered`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7162898/1983854)

Comment: @fedorqui no effect at all. Stil "buffering"

Answer (score 6):

For other tags:

awk

```
awk '/ID: 1$/ {print; getline; print}'
```

sed, very similar

```
sed -n '/ID: 1$/ {p;n;p}'
```

and bash

```
while read line; do if [[ $line == *"ID: 1" ]]; then echo "$line"; read line; echo "$line"; fi; done
```

Comment: and that's the problem with not cutting-and-pasting.

Answer (score 5):

Another simple script using `awk`

```
awk '/ID: 1/{line[NR]; line[NR+1]}; NR in line' file
```

will give output as:-

```
    ID: 1
Value: 25
    ID: 1
Value: 22
    ID: 1
Value: 23
```

`NR` is a special `awk` variable which stores the record number. All we do is match a pattern, and get the `Nth` and `N+1th` record in the line to print in the file and ensure that the record to be printed is well within the max range in that line (`NR in line`).

Comment: This is first time I have seen this kind of use for `NR`... +1 for creativity. Hopefully I will remember it...

Answer (score 1):

A solution using GNU `sed` (sometimes available as `gsed` on BSD systems):

```
$ sed -n -e '/ID: 1/,+1p' data.in
    ID: 1
Value: 25
    ID: 1
Value: 22
    ID: 1
Value: 23
```

Explanation: The `sed` script "`/ID: 1/,+1p`" applies the `p` (print) command on all lines of the input in the range `/ID: 1/` to `+1`, i.e every line matching the regular expression "`ID: 1`" and "one line further along" (the `+n` address is a GNU extension to the POSIX standard).

The `-n` flag to `sed` ensures that nothing other than what the `p` command prints gets printed ("suppress automatic printing of pattern space").

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/ID: 1$/!d;n' file
```

Delete any line that is not `ID: 1` and then print it and the next.