# Linux bash: grep from stream and write to file

Tags: linux, bash, grep, pipe, tail

I have a log file A that is constantly updated (but it is rolled over) and I need to constantly filter it's content and write to a persistent file.

**TL;DR**
I need to:

```
tail -f A.log | grep "keyword" >> B.log
```

But this command does not write anything to `B.log`.

Research only got me complex stuff that is not my case. My guess is that I'm missing some simple concept.

This is not the same question marked as [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161821/how-to-grep-a-continuous-stream), as the grep works and I have it's output if I don't try to write it to a file. The problem is the file.

Comment: The simple concept is called "buffering".

Comment: @Thor nope. "grep" works just fine. Write to file doesn't.

Comment: @WebertS.Lima The output to file will work if `--line-buffered` is included

Comment: @Leon oh, you're right. Post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @WebertS.Lima rather up vote the answer on the related question +1

Comment: @Leon just did it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If just `grep`, without writing to the file, works, you encountered a buffering "problem". I/O buffering, unless manually implemented by the program will get handled by the libc. If the program's stdout is a *termial*, buffering will be line-based. If not, the libc buffers output until the buffer reached a size limit.

On Linux, meaning with `glibc` you can use the `stdbuf` command to configure that buffering:

```
tail -f A.log | stdbuf -oL grep "keyword" >> B.log
```

`-oL` specifies that the output stream should be line-buffered.

Comment: That works too. Thank you.

Comment: @WebertS.Lima While `--line-buffered` is specific to `grep`, `stdbuf` can be used for any program which is linked against glibc and leaves buffering to the libc.

Comment: noted! =) I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: @WebertS.Lima Uh, I need to correct me. Since `--line-buffered` is not POSIX compatible, it is not portable as well. In that case `stdbuf` is just fine.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much for your concern.