# awk and data stream through pipe not working

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I am facing an issue today with awk command and data stream using fifo under ubuntu 14.04.

I have a writer.sh providing data

```
#!/bin/bash

PIPE_NAME="pipe.fifo"
DATA="dataA,dataB"

# create fifo if doesn't exist
if ! [ -p "$PIPE_NAME" ]; then
    mkfifo $PIPE_NAME
fi
# keep fifo openned
sleep 10000 > $PIPE_NAME & 

while [[ true ]];
do
    echo $DATA > $PIPE_NAME
    sleep 1
done
```

which is working fine.

On another shell, if i write the command:

```
cat pipe.fifo|grep data|awk -F, '{print $1}'
```

**I don't get anything**.

I've tried creating a dataList.txt file with the following content:

```
dataA,dataB
dataA,dataB
dataA,dataB
```

The following command:

```
cat dataList.txt|grep data|awk -F, '{print $1}'
```

produces the expected result:

```
dataA
dataA
dataA
```

Note: The grep command doesn't have any interest here but in my application, it is useful to get only data matching a certain pattern.

Do you have any idea of what I misunderstand ?

Comment: What are the content of pipe.fifo ?

Comment: pipe.fifo is the fifo created in the writer.sh script with mkfifo. The only data in this fifo are the ones generated by writer.sh script with line "echo $DATA > $PIPE_NAME"

Comment: As long as the input stream is open, grep may buffer its output when not writing to the terminal.  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161821/how-to-grep-a-continuous-stream

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however, using pipe.fifo or dataList.txt has no difference on the grep output. In other words, both cat dataList.txt|grep data and cat pipe.fifo|grep data produce the same ouput. The difference is if awk is added through a pipe.

Comment: Just to be clear, you tried the line-buffered option: `grep --line-buffered data` ?

Comment: That's not a great way to keep the pipe open. Perhaps your want `while :; do echo $DATA; sleep 1; done > "$PIPE_NAME"` instead?

Comment: I've tried "grep --line-buffered data" without success (same behaviour as what I explain above). I also tried your solution chepner but without a giant sleep in the fifo, i can't keep it opened :/ If you have any other idea, you're very welcome to share..

Comment: `grep` isn't blocking on its input, `awk` is, because `grep` is buffering its output. `grep` won't exit (and flush its buffer) until `writer.sh` closes its end of the pipe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first write to the pipe in `writer.sh` will block until something reads from the pipe. I'd suggest writing `writer.sh` like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

pipe_name="pipe.fifo"
data="dataA,dataB"

[ -p "$pipe_name" ] || mkfifo "$pipe_name"

while :; do
    echo "$data"
    sleep 1
done > "$pipe_name"
```

Here, the pipe will stay open until your `while` loop exits.

If `grep` is buffering its output, then it is continuously reading from the pipe as data arrives, but it won't *output* anything to the pipe to `awk` until that buffer is full or until it exists. Since `writer.sh` is in an infinite loop, you just have to wait until the buffer is full.

Since the combination of `grep | awk` is somewhat of an anti-pattern (since `awk` can do its own filtering), you can replace your reader with

```
awk -F, '/data/ {print $1}' pipe.fifo
```

which, since it is writing to the terminal, will not buffer its output.

Comment: With your solution, awk is giving me a result only if I stop the while loop in the writer. I would rather have a "real time" solution but i'm starting to think using a combination of pipes/commands is simply not the best way. And i'll start working on a specific script for that. Thanks for the solution anyway, it's still simpler