# View a live log of a file, only echoing lines matching a certain criteria

Tags: linux, bash, macos, unix

Ok so let's say I have a file called `system.log`, inside this file are thousands of lines of log stuff.

Within those lines are a couple of lines I'd like to see.

```
Jun 20 18:28:54 Wills-MacBook-Pro SpringBoard[75216]: MyApp 
initialized.
Jun 20 18:28:54 Wills-MacBook-Pro SpringBoard[75216]: MyApp error on 
line 2
```

I'd like to see them in console, but not

```
Jun 20 18:28:54 Wills-MacBook-Pro SpringBoard[75216]: SomethingElse initialized.
```

Sort of like a

```
tail -f system.log (echo if MyApp in line)
```

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, simply pipe it through a `grep` command.

```
tail -f system.log | grep MyApp
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers here, I'd recommend using `multitail`.
It's pretty intuitive.

Here's how I would use it to filter out only the lines of interest and append them to a new logfile

`multitail -e "MyApp" system.log`

The `-e` is used for regular expression followed by the criteria.

Furthermore, you can save all your matches to a new file by simply adding the append flag.

`multitail -a append_to_new_file.log -e "MyApp" system.log`

[Here's the man page for more info](https://linux.die.net/man/1/multitail)
and you can find more examples [here](https://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/examples.php)

Answer (score 0):

> Within those lines are a couple of lines I'd like to see

Then you shouldn't use `tail` command since it outputs only the last 10 lines.
The soln is

```
cat system.log | grep MyApp
```

a simple grep pipelining does the trick.

Comment: Cat isn't autoupdating like `tail -f` is

Comment: `tail` does much more than output the last ten lines. OP wants to use [tail following](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18760/how-does-the-tail-commands-f-parameter-work)

Comment: @Jedi I know that, the OP doesnt mentions anything about other requirement.

Comment: @Will very correct, for that we have: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161821/how-to-grep-a-continuous-stream