# How to send output to a file continuously from a piped linux command?

Tags: linux, bash, grep, output-buffering

Below command generates output every second for 60 seconds.

```
sar -n DEV  1 60 | grep lo
```

If I redirect it to a file, the file sar.log is updated continuously i.e. every second

```
sar -n DEV  1 60 > sar.log &
```

However, as soon as pipe it and then redirect it to a file, it populates the file sar.log only after it has finished i.e. after 60 seconds.

```
sar -n DEV 1 60 | grep lo > sar.log &
```

How do I grep and redirect to a file so that the log file is updated continuously i.e. every second

I am ok with using something other than grep if it serves my purpose of selecting something and redirecting to a file every second.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With GNU grep: Add option `--line-buffered` to use line buffering on output.  This can cause a performance penalty.

Answer (score 2):

I found that [How to 'grep' a continuous stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161821/how-to-grep-a-continuous-stream) is also a good answer.

```
sar -n DEV 1 10 | stdbuf -o0 grep lo > sar.log &
```