# How to colorize logs for docker container

Tags: docker, logging, grep

I have container which in logs sometimes write key word which is for me important, and I want to highlight this word in color in my terminal, but also important is still see all content logs in real time (--follow). I just tried command

```
docker logs -f my_app --tail=100 | grep --color -E '^myWord'
```

but not working.

So exist some way to do this ?

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: Can you be more specific about "not working"? You might also be interested in this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161821/how-to-grep-a-continuous-stream

Comment: after execute above command I see only cursor event in logs will appire keyWord

Answer (score 27):

I use **ccze**. as @aimless said, **grc** is the great utility also. It easy to install by `sudo apt install ccze` for debian/ubuntu-like OS

But if you want to colorize stderr, you need to redirect stderr output to stdout. For example:

```
docker logs -f my-app 2>&1 | ccze -m ansi
```

arg `-m ansi` helps if you want to scroll output normally

**UPD**:
ccze can be very slow. If you encounter this, try running ccze with the nolookups option: `ccze -o nolookups`.
originally answered - https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/461390/83391

Comment: Here is a function version of it `dockerlogscolor() { docker logs $@ 2>&1 | ccze -m ansi ; }` for easy usage: `dockerlogscolor -f my-app`

Comment: it's very slow. without `| ccze` logs are printed in a second. with it, I wait for minute or longer. it depends on logs amount.

Comment: @naXastandswithUkraine try with option  `-o nolookups`

Answer (score 11):

Try this.

```
docker logs -f my_app --tail=100 | grep --color=always -E '^myWord'
```

Note the "--color=**always**" argument.

Another option would be to use something like https://github.com/jlinoff/colorize. I wrote it to specifically address situations like this. For example it has the ability to specify different colors for each pattern (see the help for details).

Here is an example of how to use it for your case.

```
$ curl -L https://github.com/jlinoff/colorize/releases/download/v0.8.1/colorize-linux-amd64 --out colorize
$ chmod a+x colorize
$ ./colorize -h
$ docker logs -f my_app --tail=100 | ./colorize '^myWord'
$ # really make it standout.
$ docker logs -f my_app --tail=100 | ./colorize -c red+greenB+bold '^myWord'
```

Comment: This is gold! Very convenient

Answer (score 1):

try [grc](https://github.com/garabik/grc). Follow the instruction to install and just pipe the logs output:

```
docker logs -app | grc
```

Comment: Generic Colouriser 1.9
grc [options] command [args]
Options:")
-e --stderr    redirect stderr. If this option is selected,
               do not automatically redirect stdout
-s --stdout    redirect stdout, even if -e is selected
-c name --config=name    use name as configuration file for grcat
--colour=word  word is one of: on, off, auto