# grep - show two parts of matching line

Tags: regex, grep, zsh

I've read through the man page of grep and tried few things, none of them worked, at least not for me.

I want to extract a good readable line while tailing a log.
This is a generic line in a log file I want to beautify:

```
26 Jan 2018 08:32:29,309 [TEXT] (myService-0) long.text.I.dont.care.about.but.is.different.in.every.line: [OTHERTEXT] Text im actually interested in
```

What I want is this:

```
26 Jan 2018 08:32:29,309 [TEXT] [OTHERTEXT] Text im actually interested in
```

I know that with `grep -o -e ".*\[TEXT\]"` I get the first part, and with `grep -o -e "\[OTHERTEXT\].*"`, I get the second part.

But this is not displayed on one line, also not if I combine it into `grep -o -e ".*\[TEXT\]" -e "\[OTHERTEXT\].*"`

`[TEXT]` and `[OTHERTEXT]` always are there and are my 'separators', so can be used to support extracting the parts I need.

I initially thought I could use `grep -o -e "(.*\[TEXT\]).*(\[OTHERTEXT\].*)"` and then somehow use the matching groups `$1` and `$2`, but either I don't see it or there is no way to do so.

Is there a way to achieve what I want?

Preferred is using `grep` (simply because I want to learn more about it), but if that is not possible then `awk` or `sed` are fine as well, it just has to be usable with a `tail -f`.

And I'm also open to other approaches to get to that point, so let me know what ways exist to get there.

Thanks, Tobias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/(\[TEXT]).*(\[OTHERTEXT])/\1 \2/' file.log

26 Jan 2018 08:32:29,309 [TEXT] [OTHERTEXT] Text im actually interested in
```

This `sed` matches a pattern between `[TEXT]` and `[OTHERTEXT]` and captures them in 2 groups. In replacement it puts those markers back using back-refrences `\1 \2`

Comment: That works great, thanks! I just had to do minor changes: `sed -E "s/(.*\[TEXT\]).*(\[OTHERTEXT\].*)/\1 \2/"`

Comment: Matching before and after test using `.*` is not really needed. Just `sed -E 's/(\[TEXT]).*(\[OTHERTEXT])/\1 \2/' ` should work fine as well.

Comment: Based on James Browns answer, a shorter sed for this specific use case:  `sed -E "s/\].*\[//"`

Comment: Actually `sed -E "s/\].*\[//"` might work for this line but if there is another `[...]` before `[TEXT]` or after `[OTHERTEXT]` then it will fail.

Answer (score 1):

Using awk you could replace everything between `]` and `[` with `] [`:

```
$ awk 'sub(/\].*\[/,"] [")' file
26 Jan 2018 08:32:29,309 [TEXT] [OTHERTEXT] Text im actually interested in
```

Answer (score 0):

pipe your grep into

```
<your grep> | sed "s/(myService-0).*[OTHERTEXT]/(myService-0)[OTHERTEXT]/"
```

Comment: `[OTHERTEXT]` is called a bracket expression that matches each character inside `[...]` individually.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that with `perl`

```
$ # note that this will print empty lines when no match is found
$ perl -lne 'print /(.*\[TEXT\] ).*(\[OTHERTEXT\].*)/' ip.txt
26 Jan 2018 08:32:29,309 [TEXT] [OTHERTEXT] Text im actually interested in
$ # you can avoid empty lines by checking for match first
$ perl -lne '/(.*\[TEXT\] ).*(\[OTHERTEXT\].*)/ && print $1,$2' ip.txt
26 Jan 2018 08:32:29,309 [TEXT] [OTHERTEXT] Text im actually interested in
```

since you are processing `tail -f` output, you might need buffering control, see [How to 'grep' a continuous stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161821/how-to-grep-a-continuous-stream/7162169#7162169) for example

Answer (score 0):

You probably need *sed* for doing what you want:

```
sed -E 's/(.*\[TEXT]).*(\[OTHERTEXT])/\1 \2/'
```

But to answer to your question about how to show matches in *grep*, yes it is possible with the option `-o`. This option will show only matched parts of the matching line. Nevertheless, if you use

```
grep -o -e ".*\[TEXT\]" -e "\[OTHERTEXT\].*"
```

you will get your matched parts but in separate lines.

Another possibility could be to use look-ahead and look-behind expressions, but it cannot work in your case.