# Tails -f sort data with multiple pipes

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have several rows of data that looks the following:

```
255.255.255.255 -  - [dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss] "GET /index.html?parameter1=valueN HTTP/1.1" 200 -
255.255.255.255 -  - [dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss] "GET /index.html?parameter2=valueN HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

However I want to only show this part of the line:

```
parameter=value
```

But it must be done by a command similar to this because I need the continual output that tails can deliver:

```
tails -f <file.log> | whatever
```

I can remove both the first part of the line and the last part, but I am unable to figure out how to achieve that in one line. I have the following script that will do as I want, but it only works with cat, and not with tails:

```
cat file.log | cut -d'?' -f2 | sed 's/ HTTP\/1\.1\" 200 \-/ /g' | grep -E "parameter1|parameter2"
```

Results in:

```
parameter1=valueN
parameter2=valueN
```

I have also tried several other commands with cut, tr and grep that brings me somewhat closer to what I want, however still doesn't match what I've shown above. What do I do?

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is. I'm pretty sure you are simply a victim of buffering (this is a common FAQ) but I'm hesitant to close this as a duplicate until you can confirm that things work with the obvious fix. `tail -f  file.log | sed -un 's%.* "GET /index\.html?\(parameter[12]=value[^ ]*\) HTTP/1\.[01]" 200 -.*%\1%p'` on GNU `sed`; e.g. MacOS requires `-l` instead of `-u` for unbuffered.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirecting tail output into a program](/questions/36525541/redirecting-tail-output-into-a-program)

Comment: Maybe a better duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161821/how-to-grep-a-continuous-stream

Comment: See: `man sed | grep buffer` and `man grep | grep buffer`

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I've also tried using commands to avoid the buffering problem, but yet tail doesn't allow me to pipe more than once!
I've tried using "stdbuf -oL" before grepping as well as "--line-buffered" none of them solve my problem.

Comment: Upload file.log somewhere.

Comment: `sed` can contain multiple substitutions as separate steps, ie. `sed 's/1/X/;s/2/Y/;s/3/Z/;.....'` I don't see a need to all `grep -E` after using `sed`. Also, your example output implies you want to remove any numbers that are trailing after both `param` and `value`. ? That can be fixed with a `sed` command as well (if I understand your Q correctly). Good luck.

Comment: `echo "255.255.255.255 -  - [dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss] "GET /index.html?parameter1=valueN HTTP/1.1" 200 -" | sed 's/^.*[?]//;s/ .*$//;s/[0-9]//g'` produces `parameter=valueN`. Its left as a learning exercize for the reader to remove the `N` from `valueN` ;-) . Good luck.

Comment: I'm surprized that `stdbuf -oL` isn't working for you, (but my system doesn't have that, so I can't confirm the options you are using). I would run a second window that just displays  the raw output from `tail -f` so you can see if there are pauses created by the producer program that you might not anticipate. AND update your Q with your best attempt including the call to `stdbuf`, as this is what you need to fix. AND your Q subject mentions `sort` but it's not in the body of your q (is it?) . A source file has to be closed for `sort` to work, if can't take input from `tail -f file`. GoodLuck.

Comment: Maybe you just have a problem with log rotation. Have you looked at `tail -F`? It will tell tail to not just wait for changes in the file but to also check if the file was moved and a new one with the same name was created (due to log rotation), and if so it will automatically reopen the new log file.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @shellter!

The following command solved my problem:

```
tail -f file.log | sed 's/^.*[?]//;s/ .*$//;s/[0-9]//g'
```

However now I get "..." whenever there is an output that doesn't match the expression, I'd rather have nothing printed. Also there are issues with non-unicode characters that I will be looking more into. Thanks!

Comment: The `sed -n` script in my first comment might get you closer to what you want. Maybe simplify the regex to `sed -n 's/.*[?]\([^ ]*[^ 0-9]\)[0-9] .*/\1/p'`

Comment: Thank you, but this returns nothing to the console