# How to redirect docker logs with grep command to a text file?

Tags: linux, docker, grep

For finding specific logs from the docker logs, I am using the grep with docker logs as below

```
docker logs -f docker_container 2>&1 | grep "KafkaRecordGenerator:197"
```

Which is giving the correct result in the console. I need to redirect these logs to a text file. For that, I used the below command

```
docker logs -f docker_container 2>&1 | grep "KafkaRecordGenerator:197" >> test.txt
```

Here the new file test.txt is created but the output is not redirected to the test.txt file. How to redirect the docker logs with grep command to a text file?

Comment: Check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/7162898/11344502

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the anemyte's comment, --line-buffered with grep command fixed my problem. The final command is,

```
docker logs -f docker_container 2>&1 | grep --line-buffered "KafkaRecordGenerator:197" >> test.txt
```