# Optimize sed on logcat

Tags: bash, shell, optimization, sed, logcat

I've been using `grep` and `sed` on some logcat output to make it more readable and I noticed my output was noticeably slower than just `grep`-ing the output.

I understand sed is obviously going to add more runtime, but I wanted to check for any optimization techniques.

My commands look something like this for reference:

`adb logcat | grep arg | sed $'s/{/\\\n{/g`

Comment: can you define 'noticeably slower'? eg, 'a 5GB file takes 5 secs with grep and 10 secs with grep+sed'? what happens if you pull the `arg* match into the sed via a range/match? or replace grep+sed with a single awk call to do the the same thing?

Comment: @markp-fuso logcat gives continuous output. Without sed it gives a new line about ever .1 sec, whereas with sed it's about every 2 sec

Comment: I don't have `adb` running locally so can't comment on the `sed` performance but would be curious how `adb logcat | awk '/arg/ { gsub("{","\n{"); print}'` performs

Comment: @markp-fuso That runs leagues faster. Thank you

Comment: `sed` slowing things down so much seems unbelievable. When you get output every 2 seconds, does that mean you get just a single line every 2 seconds, or do you get a big block of lines after every pause? For the latter case, this would only be a buffering issue but not an actual speed issue. Here you could try `grep --line-buffered ... | sed --unbuffered ...`.

Answer (score 0):

The [useless `grep`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep) is well-documented and easy to get rid of.

```sh
adb logcat | sed $'/\\*arg/s/{/\\\n{/g'
```

To briefly reiterate the linked web page, anything that looks like `grep 'x' | sed 'y'` can be refactored to `sed '/x/y'` (and similarly for `grep 'x' | awk 'y'`, which reduces to `awk '/x/ y'`). `sed` and Awk are both generalized regex tools which can do everything `grep` can do (though in fairness some complex `grep` options are tedious to reimplement in a `sed` or Awk script; but this is obviously not one of these cases).

However, `*arg*` is not a well-defined regex; so I have to guess what you actually mean.

- `*` at the beginning of a regex isn't well-defined; but many `grep` implementations will understand it to mean a literal asterisk. If that's not what you meant, probably take away the first `\\*`.
- `arg*` is exactly equivalent to `ar`; if you don't care whether there are `g` characters after the match, just don't specify them. But perhaps you actually meant `arg` followed by anything?
- But then I guess you probably meant just `arg` (implicitly preceded by and followed by anything).

In case it's not already obvious, `*` is not a wildcard character in regex. Instead, it says to repeat the preceding expression as many times as possible, zero or more (and thus the way to say "any string at all" in regex is `.*`, i.e. the "any character (except newline)" wildcard character `.` repeated zero or more times).

Also, `grep` (and `sed`, and Awk) look for the regex anywhere in a line (unless you put in explicit regex anchors or use `grep -x` or equivalent options in `sed` or Awk) so you don't need to specify "preceded by anything" or "followed by anything".

The Bash "C-style string" `$'...'` offers some conveniences, but also requires any literal backslash to be doubled. So `$'/\\*/'` is equivalent to `'/\*/'` in regular single quotes.

The reason the `sed` slows you down is probably [buffering,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37034112/874188) but getting rid of the useless `grep` also coincidentally gets rid of that buffering.

Comment: I apologize for the poor example. `*arg*` was supposed to be a placeholder since I can't really disclose my the actual arg I'm passing to grep (NDA stuff). I should've realized using * was a bad idea in a regex type problem

Comment: I'll probably leave those things in now that I wrote them. Does this answer otherwise solve your problem?

Comment: I tried `adb logcat | sed $'/arg/s/{/\\\n{/g'` but it's not filtering the logs that my original `grep` got rid of

Comment: If your `arg` was a shell variable, that changes the question. If your `arg` was a regex which has different meanings to `grep` and `sed`, that could explain it. Your question doesn't suggest anything remotely like either of these so I have answered the question you actually asked. But if you can edit your question to provide a [mre] where this approach doesn't work, I can try to update this answer.

Comment: ... Or maybe just accept this answer, or provide one of your own and accept that, and ask a new question with your *actual* requirements. Moving the goalposts after you have received answers is always more or less problematic.