# Invoke jq on every new json object printed by Python script, not just on completion

Tags: python, json, jq

I have a python script that watches a socket and when data is received it writes JSON to stdout.

This sample script below illustrates the behaviour, outputting new JSON every 3 seconds.

```
import json, time

def new_json(n):
    frame = {
        "Iteration": n,
        "Field0": 0,
        "Field1": 1,
        "Field2": 2
    }
    print(json.dumps(frame))

new_json(1)
time.sleep(3)
new_json(2)
time.sleep(3)
new_json(3)
```

The output of this is:

```
{"Iteration": 1, "Field0": 0, "Field1": 1, "Field2": 2}
{"Iteration": 2, "Field0": 0, "Field1": 1, "Field2": 2}
{"Iteration": 3, "Field0": 0, "Field1": 1, "Field2": 2}
```

If i pipe this into `jq` using `python3 jqtest.py | jq .` it only prints the JSON when the script has completely finished.

How can i invoke `jq` for every new JSON object received during execution, not just at the end?

Comment: Pipes are buffered; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161821/how-to-grep-a-continuous-stream and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe

Comment: just like this : `python3 jqtest.py | jq --unbuffered .`

Comment: @Freeman This didn't work for me. From the accepted answer i think the buffering is occurring before it reaches jq?

Comment: BTW, you _will_ see your content piped through jq earlier than the end of the Python program _if the Python program's output is long enough to fill the buffer_. (And jq is only invoked once, at the start of the pipeline; the problem is that nothing is written to its stdin until the buffer flushes, so while it's running, it's also spending its time idle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unbuffer python's stdout, e.g.:

```py
python3 -u jqtest.py | jq '.'
```