# How to start a process as running in background?

Tags: c, linux, daemon, background-process, system-calls

I've done a `fork` and and then an `exec` but I don't know how to start it in the background.

Should I use an argument after the `exec`? If so, which is it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116701/how-can-a-c-c-program-put-itself-into-background

Comment: Which platform are you trying this on, please?

Comment: For at  least Linux (or BSD) see: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/daemon.3.html

Comment: oh sorry, i'm using linux

Comment: possible duplicate of [running a process in background in c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18916656/running-a-process-in-background-in-c)

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18916656/running-a-process-in-background-in-c

Comment: @AB: I feel in the question you linked the accepted answer is wrong. As the `fork()`ed process is not backgrounded.

Comment: You might also consider changing directory to somewhere on the root filesystem as a daemon so that your long-running background process doesn't prevent filesystems being dismounted.

Comment: @AB: Referring my previous commet: "*wrong*" as answer to this question here. So the question you linked is not a duplicate to this one here.

Answer (score 2):

If you simply want to background a process use [`daemon()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/daemon.3.html).

If you want to spawn off a process that then backgrounds itself 1st use [`fork()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) and inside this 1st child call `fork()` again letting the 2nd child call [`exec*()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) for the process to be backgrounded. Let the initial parent [`wait()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) for the 1st child.

As the parent of the second child (the process `fork()`ed 1st) dies, the `exec*()`ed process will be reaped by `init`.

---

Note: The pattern above is sometimes referred to as "*double-forking*". See also here: [Why fork() twice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10932592/694576) (and links from there)

Another interesting set of answers on this is here: [Linux: Difference between forking twice and daemon(ise)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26405391/linux-difference-between-forking-twice-and-daemonise)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Hu Basile, how fast, I was just about to add the links ... :-) Thx!