# (kernel simple programming) I want to know why pids are displayed like this

Tags: c, linux, kernel

I am practicing making device driver programming.

my goal was to get current task's pid, and parent task's pid.

furthermore, I get grand(parent's parent) task's pid.

this is source code.

```
struct task_struct * current_task = current;
struct task_struct * parent_task = current_task->parent;

printk("current pid : %d, current_task->pid);
printk("parent task pid : %d\n", parent_task->pid);
printk("grand pid : %d\n", parent_task->parent->pid);
```

---

this is result..
(I ran this 3 times.)

> current pid : 2850
>   parent task pid : 2846
>   grand parent task : 1692
>
> current pid : 2872
>   parent task pid : 2864
>   grand parent task : 1692
>
> current pid : 2891
>   parent task pid : 2887
>   grand parent task : 1692
>
> grand parent task's pid is always 1692.

current's one and parent's one are increasing.
I am just wondering why...
It will be helpful if someone answer me..
Thanks for reading.

Comment: There is nice [explanation here on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446727/how-does-linux-determine-the-next-pid)

Answer (score 0):

you have not specified whether you are using IDE for writing and executing the code.
In the case if you are using it

`grand parent task` is IDE (which is constant till you close and reopen it.

`parent task id` - when you execute the program, the program is called by a process which is created by the IDE and each time you run the program it is called by new processes created by IDE
(when you program terminates, the calling process created by your IDE is also terminates).
`current pid` is your process id

Process ID's are assigned in increment order by os.