# Why do pids jump in a container?

Tags: linux, docker, containers, pid

Entering a container (e.g. `docker run` or `docker exec`) makes the PID of **next** created process jump ahead, why is that?

For example, in the image below the second process in the container (`ps`) is assigned PID 10, not PID 2:

[image: example]

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3457108/10268515), Linux appears to be allocating PIDs in a sequence, is that not always the case?

Comment: Is there a case where your application code actually depends on this behavior?  Can you delete the images from your question and replace them with a [mcve], showing as text the code you're running and the output it's producing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talked with once of runc's maintainers, Aleksa Sarai, and he explained why this is happening.

By design, the golang runtime spawns several threads to manage a process. [runc](https://github.com/opencontainers/runc) is written in golang, and when building/execing into the container, there is a short time where the runc process is running inside the container (before execing the user requested executable, e.g. bash in `docker exec bash`). In Linux, threads and processes are both identified with ids from the same pool, so the go runtime threads are counted in the container pid namespace, leading to the pid jump I described.