# Bash array with loop

Tags: shell

I wrote a Bash script which tries to find a process and run the process if it had stopped.
This is the script.

```
#!/bin/bash
process=thin
path=/home/deepak/abc/
initiate=thin start -d

process_id=`ps -ef | pgrep $process | wc -m`

if [ "$process_id" -gt "0" ]; then
  echo "The process process is running!!"
else     
  cd $path    
  $initiate
  echo "Oops the process has stopped"    
fi
```

This worked fine and I thought of using arrays so that i can form a loop use this script to check multiple processes. So I modified my script like this

```
#!/bin/bash
process[1]=thin
path[1]=/home/deepak/abc/
initiate[1]=thin start -d

process_id=`ps -ef | pgrep $process[1] | wc -m`

if [ "$process_id" -gt "0" ]; then
  echo "Hurray the process ${process[1]} is running!!"
else
  cd ${path[1]}
  ${initiate[1]}
  echo "Oops the process has stopped"
  echo "Continue your coffee, the process has been stated again! ;)"
fi
```

I get this error if i run this script.

```
DontWorry.sh: 2: process[1]=thin: not found
DontWorry.sh: 3: path[1]=/home/deepak/abc/: not found
DontWorry.sh: 4: initiate[1]=thin start -d: not found
```

I googled to find any solution for this, most them insisted to use "#!/bin/bash" instead of "#!/bin/sh". I tried both but nothing worked. What am i missing?

Comment: It's unrelated to your problem, but you should change `pgrep $process[1]` to `pgrep ${process[1]}`.

Comment: Thanks Mark for your reply. I get this error now after adding the change which told me.
DontWorry.sh: 2: process[1]=thin: not found 
DontWorry.sh: 3:   path[1]=/home/deepak/CampusYap/: not found
DontWorry.sh: 4: initiate[1]=thin: not found 
DontWorry.sh: 6: Bad substitution 
DontWorry.sh: 15: Bad substitution

Comment: What version of `bash` are you using? Post the result of `echo $BASH_VERSION`.

Comment: The `name[subscript]=...` syntax should work with bash versions as old as 2.05b (http://web.cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/\*checkout\*/bash/manual/bashref.html?revision=1.1&root=bash#SEC80)

Comment: echo $BASH_VERSION
3.2.48(1)-release

Comment: @Deepak, I've updated my answer - you may want to have a look.

Answer (score 0):

I was not actually aware you could set arrays like that. I've always used:

```
pax> initiate=("thin start -d" "xx")
pax> echo ${initiate[0]}
thin start -d
pax> echo ${initiate[1]}
xx
```

You may need quotes around the strings. In my `bash` (4.0.33),

```
initiate[1]=thin start -d
```

is being interpreted as "set initiate[1]=thin then run start -d" because you can:

```
fspec=/etc/passwd ls -al ${fspec}
```

to set an environment variable for a single command. What version of `bash` are you running (use `bash --version`)?

*Update:*

Deepak, I've gotten that script working under the same release of `bash` as yours. See the following transcript:

```
pax> bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.48(21)-release (i686-pc-cygwin)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

pax> cat qq.sh
#!/bin/bash
process=(sleep)
path=(/)
initiate=("sleep 3600")

process_id=`ps -ef | pgrep ${process[0]} | wc -m`

if [ "$process_id" -gt "0" ]; then
    echo "Hurray the process ${process[0]} is running!!"
else
    cd ${path[0]}
    ${initiate[0]} &
    echo "Oops the process has stopped"
    echo "Continue your coffee, the process has been stated again! ;)"
fi

pax> ./qq.sh
Oops the process has stopped
Continue your coffee, the process has been stated again! ;)

pax> ./qq.sh
Hurray the process sleep is running!!

pax> ps -ef
UID     PID    PPID TTY     STIME COMMAND
pax     112       1 con  10:16:24 /usr/bin/bash
pax    4568       1 con  10:23:07 /usr/bin/sleep
pax    5924     112 con  10:23:18 /usr/bin/ps
```

Can you try the modified script in your own environment and see how it goes?

Comment: Thanks pax, I tried using quotes but still I get this error. 

My Bash version. bash --version GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (i486-pc-linux-gnu) Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Comment: What happens when you use the alternative syntax 'initiate=("thin start -d")' ?

Comment: Some errors have gone that is the string is getting assigned to the array, but "process_id=`ps -ef | pgrep ${process[0]} | wc -m`" this line throws an error. ERROR: DontWorry.sh: 6: Bad substitution

Comment: Sorry, @Deepak, did you change all *three* arrays to the new format? If you're still setting process[1], your pgrep *will* fail since it's using process[0]. I suggest you try my script in the update and see if that works. It works fine for me in that bash version (albeit under Cygwin).

Comment: Pax, Thank you so much. It works great. But if i use "sh filename.sh" to execute it in the command line instead of "./filename.sh" i get some errors. Why is it?

Comment: That would depend on how sh is running the script. sh is the posix shell under some operating systems and *should* honor the shebang line at the top of your script. But it *may* be the Bourne shell on other systems - in other words, you may be running the script under the wrong shell.

Answer (score 0):

Deepak Prasanna, you may want to rethink the way you are monitoring the process.

[lhunath gives reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696839/how-do-i-write-a-bash-script-to-restart-a-process-if-it-dies/697064#697064) for not using `ps` to monitor/restart processes, and also
a simple script wrapper to achieve the goal in a cleaner manner.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my @processes = ({process=>'thin',
                  path=>'/home/deepak/abc/',
                  initiate=>'thin start -d'
                 },
                 # more records go here...
                );

for $p (@processes) {
   my $cmd = 'ps -ef | pgrep ' . $p->{process} . ' | wc -m';
   if (`$cmd` > 0) {
     print "The process process is running!!\n";
   } else {
     exec('cd ' . $p->{path} . '; ' .  
          $p->{$initiate}. '; '.
          'echo Oops the process has stopped'); 
   }
}
```