# How do I monitor two processes & do something if one exits (bash scripting)?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I'm trying to write a wrapper script in bash to automate startup and shutdown of three programs I need to run simultaneously:

```
#!/bin/bash
gnome-screensaver-command -i -n aeolus-wrapper.sh &
aeolus &
qjackctl
```

After starting them, I need to monitor aeolus and qjackctl and kill the remaining two processes if either aeolus or qjackctl exits:

```
# if aeolus exits, kill gnome-screensaver-command and qjackctl
# if qjackctl exits, kill gnome-screensaver-command and aeolus
```

This is where I'm stuck. I was intrigued by [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696839/how-do-i-write-a-bash-script-to-restart-a-process-if-it-dies) that shows how to use an `until` loop to monitor a process and restart it if it dies, but I'm not quite sure how to get from there to where I want to go. Any suggestions very welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use a while loop.  Just block and wait for a SIGCHLD to tell you that one of the processes has terminated.  In the trap, kill the remaining running processes.  For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -m
trap 'list=$( jobs -rp ); test -n "$list" && kill $list' CHLD
cmd1 &
cmd2 &
cmd3 &
wait
```

This will run 3 commands.  When one exits, the other two will be sent SIGTERM.

Comment: Thank you. This looks like what I want, except for one thing: If I close qjackctl, it does kill aeolus and gnome-screensaver-command. But if I close aeolus, it does not successfully kill qjackctl. Instead, on the command line I see "jack main caught signal 12," and the wrapper script continues to wait. (Note that qjackctl is a GUI frontend for jackd; when you start aeolus, it starts jackd automatically.)

Comment: It sounds like aeolus is catching the SIGTERM and sending SIGSYS to jackd.  You need to figure out what signal you can send to aeolus to successfully terminate it.

Comment: Turned out to be: (1) qjackctl is actually qjackctl.bin, and needs to be listed as such; (2) jackd needs to be included explicitly in the list. So this is what works: 
`#!/bin/bash
set -m
trap 'list=$( jobs -rp ); test -n "$list" && kill $list' CHLD
gnome-screensaver-command -i -n aeolus-wrapper.sh &
jackd -T -ndefault -dalsa -dhw:0 -r44100 -p1024 -n2 &
aeolus &
qjackctl.bin &
wait` With approriate line breaks, of course, which aren't shown here. Many thanks, again, for the help.

Answer (score 1):

```
if [ "a$(pgrep aeolus)" != "a" ] ; 
then 
    pkill gnome-screensaver-command 
    pkill qjackctl
fi
```

same for `qjackctl`

Another syntax,

```
if pgrep aeolus
then 
    pkill gnome-screensaver-command 
    pkill qjackctl
fi
```

Comment: Also `if ! pgrep aeolus`; then ...`

Comment: @SiegeX First I used `if !` syntax. It didn't work on my pc for some reasone. So I edited. `kill` is also now replaced with `pkill`. In fact I kept those kill lines for OP to edit.