# how to restart only certain processes using supervisorctl?

Tags: supervisord

I'm running a few processes using supervisord, named process1, process2, ..., process8. If I want to restart process{1-4}, how can I do that with supervisorctl?

Answer (score 213, accepted):

supervisord supports [process groups](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#group-x-section-settings). You can group processes into named groups and manage them collectively.

```
[unix_http_server]
file=%(here)s/supervisor.sock

[supervisord]
logfile=supervisord.log
pidfile=supervisord.pid

[program:cat1]
command=cat

[program:cat2]
command=cat

[program:cat3]
command=cat

[group:foo]
programs=cat1,cat3

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix://%(here)s/supervisor.sock

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface
```

supervisorctl command can be called with a group name:

```
supervisorctl restart foo:
```

as well as with multiple process names:

```
supervisorctl restart foo:cat1 cat2
```

Comment: It's amazing how non-trivial it was to find out that a colon needs to be appended when issuing commands to a process group. Thank you.

Comment: Agreed. I think `supervisorctl restart foo:*` makes what's happening clearer.

Comment: So to directly answer the OP's question, you can't directly restart a specific process. You can only restart groups, which requires a group tag?

Comment: @Cerin From my own testing, I came that exact same conclusion. Speaking anecdotally, I have tended to see a group at the end of .conf files containing all processes. As a repeated observation, this made no sense. Now it makes complete sense :)

Comment: You made my day :)

Comment: @mafrosis I did it in two steps: 1. enter `supervisorctl`, 2. `restart foo` It looks like no colons are needed this way

Comment: @guival, that doesn't work. Running supervisorctl on it's own opens up supervisor's own command line, and then running restart foo while omitting the colon yields the same error that would come out of running it as a single line command.

@ mher, thanks for that!

Answer (score 16):

Since `supervisorctl` accepts multiple processes on the command line, you can take advantage of shell brace expansion (e.g. in Bash) to control multiple processes:

```
supervisorctl restart process{1..4}
```

is expanded *by the shell* into

```
supervisorctl restart process1 process2 process3 process4
```

as if you had typed that out explicitly.