# Does Supervisord process need restart after changes to Laravel file?

Tags: php, laravel, queue

I am using Supervisord to monitor a queue in Laravel 4.2. This is my Supervisord config file:

```
[program:webhooks]
command=php artisan queue:work --daemon --queue=webhooks --tries=3 --sleep=5
directory=/var/www/html/app
stdout_logfile=/var/www/html/app/app/storage/logs/webhooks_supervisord.log
redirect_stderr=true
autostart=true
autorestart=true
```

As I see in the Laravel docs:

> Daemon queue workers do not restart the framework before processing
>   each job.

From what I can tell, this means that if I make a change to one of the files in the framework, that change will not be reflected in the daemon processing the queue. For example, if one of my file says `echo 1;` and I change to `echo 2;`, the version of the framework that the queue is using will still say `echo 1`, until I restart the queue. To have these new changes take effect, I need to run:

```
sudo supervisorctl
supervisor> stop webhooks
supervisor> start webhooks
```

Am I correct that this is required? Or is there another way to handle this so that new changes to the files will be picked up without restarting the queue?

Answer (score 21):

You dont need to! Just do the following and the supervisor will automatically restart with fresh code.

```
$> CD /your/project/folder
$> php artisan queue:restart
```

The reason is that the artisan command will stop the queue and supervisor will force a restart again as you have set `autorestart=true` in the config.

To confirm, just do the following and see the `uptime` in the output:

```
$> sudo supervisorctl status
```

--

Additionally can do the following if you have made changes to the supervisord program's config:

```
$> sudo supervisorctl update
```

This will reload configs, add/remove as necessary, and will restart affected supervisor `programs`

Comment: This is the correct answer. Documentation ref: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#queue-workers-and-deployment

Answer (score 2):

Since the daemon queue worker loads the file only once it has to be restarted before any code changes are picked up. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9310434/3784306) is a good example on how to manage multiple related queues workers once the project gets too big to manually restart every worker.

Alternatively you could use [queue listener](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queues#running-the-queue-listener) via `php artisan queue:listen`. This option comes at a significant increase in CPU load due to the fact that the entire framework is bootstrapped from scratch after every job.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. For some reason, running
`$ php artisan queue:listen` or `$ php artisan queue:work` always resulted in the queue randomly stopping half way through jobs, even though they didn't fail. I set up Supervisor but then had the issue of the queue running an outdated version of the codebase anytime I made changes.

If you're using Sublime Text as your editor, you can add a hook to restart Supervisor each time you make edits in your Laravel project. Go to Project > Edit Project.

```
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": "."
        },
        {
            "path": "app/Http/Controllers"
        },
        {
            "path": "resources/views"
        },
        {
            "path": "database/migrations"
        }
    ],
    "on_pre_save_language": [
        {
            "command": "supervisorctl restart webhooks"
        }
    ]
}
```

So far so good. I will update my answer if things go awry.