# Laravel job doesn't update

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-queue

Need help, I think I've tried all the options.
Previously, a job was created and worked as it should, its task was to generate pdf. The problem now is that when I change the "handle" method, the job is executed as if the change hadn't happened. But they happen because when i add anything to "construct" method i can see it. It feels like the job is being cached. Now I still get my pdf file, although I just expect to see the message in the logs and that's it.

**Job starts as a supervisor**.

```
[program:worker-default]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/mysite/artisan queue:work
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root
numprocs=8
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/mysite/storage/logs/worker.log
startsecs=0
stopwaitsecs=3600
```

**Job**

```
public function __construct($order){
    Log::info(__METHOD__); // I can see changes in laravel.log

    $this->demand = $order->demand;
    $this->offer = $order->offer;}


public function handle() {
     Log::info(__METHOD__); // I do not see the changes in laravel.log
     dd(1);}
```

**What I have tried:**

- sudo supervisorctl reread
- sudo supervisorctl update
- sudo supervisorctl reload
- sudo supervisorctl restart all
- sudo service supervisor restart
- sudo supervisorctl stop all
- sudo supervisorctl start all

*supervisorctl status* shows normal uptime, no hung tasks.

- php artisan cache:clear
- php artisan config:cache
- php artisan config:clear
- php artisan optimize:clear

Supervisor vesion 3.3.1,
Laravel Framework 7.30.4, logging permissions 777

P.S. Also, job records are no longer added to the worker.log file that the supervisor writes to.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30306954/does-supervisord-process-need-restart-after-changes-to-laravel-file

Comment: @Rwd I did it. Uptime is reset. But the problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

I stopped the supervisor and started the job manually.

```
sudo service supervisor stop
php artisan queue:work
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to restart supervisor everytime you chang a job.

```
sudo service supervisor restart
```