# Django on the production server (nginx + gunicorn), after changes in the files, sometimes the changes are displayed, sometimes they are not displayed

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, gunicorn, django-caching

On the production server (nginx + gunicorn), after changes in the files, sometimes the changes are displayed, sometimes they are not displayed. After restarting the server, everything works correctly.

I thought it might be related to caches and tried different options (disabling caches, cleaning caches, etc.), but the problem remained.
Also tried deleting the `__pycache__` folders in different project directories, but that didn't help either

Comment: Changing what files? static content?

Comment: If it's static content maybe you can try force update with `Ctrl + f5`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to restart only certain processes using supervisorctl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9301494/how-to-restart-only-certain-processes-using-supervisorctl)

Comment: i guess you need to make sure server does not cache files in memory and your browser does not cache files in browser cache

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the server is required if you are making changes to the code, because, when the application is started the project code/files is loaded into the memory and any changes to it will not reflect until the server restarts.

If you are using supervisor to manage the processes, you can restart the server by

```sh
$ sudo supervisorctl restart <process_name>
```