# BASH - why the infinite loop is not infinite and failing to restart the crashed process?

Tags: linux, node.js, bash, centos

I have this following script running in my centos 7 server. its job is to run for-ever and check if xxx.js is alive, if crashed or killed, it has to restart it.

but since 3 days its failing to start my xxx.js unless i manually login to the server and apply $ ./myloop.sh &

`root     23413  0.1  0.1 113252  1640 ?        S    Nov11   0:59 /bin/bash ./myloop.sh`

Can anyone please check what is the BUG  causing it to unable to execute the xxx.js when its not running / crashed?

```
#!/bin/bash
while :
do
  # 1
  xxx=$(pgrep -f "xxx.js")
  if [[ "$xxx" ]]; then
    log1="1 - running xxx.js $1 $2"
  else
    log1="1 - re-launch xxx.js $1 $2"
    ps aux | grep "xxx.js" | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill
    sleep 1
    nohup node /var/www/html/sip-phone/xx/xxx.js &

  fi

  tt=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T")
  echo "$tt" "$log1"

  sleep 2
done
```

Comment: More immediately, the suicide problem; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11375861/no-command-executed-after-performing-kill-command-in-shell-script

Comment: No its not working, can you please check whats wrong in my script, it was working for 3 years. now since 3 days not working.

Comment: is myloop.sh running when you login to your server? Who is starting it?

Comment: YES - myloop.sh was running twice when i login to the server. root has executed the myloop.sh twice.