# Write a bash script to restart a daemon

Tags: multithreading, bash, restart, system-administration

I thought I could just use this related question: [How Do I write a bash script to restart a process if it dies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696839/how-do-i-write-a-bash-script-to-restart-a-process-if-it-dies).  @lhunath had a great answer and told me everything I might do about it was wrong, but I'm restarting a daemon process and if I'm hoping there's something I can do in a single script that works.

my process starts with a kick off script that shows the startup log, but then quits and leaves the process running off the shell:

```
>sudo ./start
R CMD Rserve --RS-conf /var/FastRWeb/code/rserve.conf --vanilla --no-save
...
Loading required package: FastRWeb
FastRWeb: TRUE
Loading data...
Rserv started in daemon mode.
>
```

The process is up and running,

> ps -ale | grep Rserve
>       1 S    33 16534     1  0  80   0 - 60022 poll_s ?        00:00:00 Rserve

Is there a simple way to wrap or call the 'start' script from bash and restart when the process dies or is this a case where PID files are actually called for?

Dang - question got closed even after pointing to a very similar question that was not closed on stackoverflow. you guys suck

Comment: while true; do sudo ./start; sleep 1; done ??

Comment: does the program provide a non-daemon mode?

Comment: also, check `pgrep` and `pidof` man pages. they might provide some insight.

Comment: the start script does a bunch of stuff i only somewhat understand and i don't want to re-engineer it into non daemon mode. maybe that's lazy... :)

Comment: the software doesn't seem to have a non-daemon mode, or its buried too deeply for me to find... @Oliver that's basically the script in the example, though i can't amend to add it anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simple way to monitor the program is to use cron: check every minute (or so) if the program still is alive, `./start` it otherwise.

As root, invoke `crontab -e`.

Append a line like this:

```
* * * * * if ! pidof Rserve 2>&1 >/dev/null; then /full/path/to/start; fi
```

This method will stay persistent, i.e., it will be executed after a reboot etc. If this is not what you want, move it to a shell script:

```
#! /bin/bash
# monitor.sh
while true; do
  if ! pidof Rserve 2>&1 >/dev/null; then /full/path/to/start; fi
  sleep 10
done
```

This script has to be started manually from the command line, and can be easily stopped with Ctrl-C.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution, if you can run the process is NON-daemon mode, is to wrap it in a script.

```
#!/bin/bash
while (true)
do
  xmessage "This is your process.  Click OK to kill and respawn"
done
```

**Edit**

Many deamons leave a lock file, usually in `/var/lock`, that contains their PID.  This keeps multiple copies of the deamon from running.

Under Linux, it is fairly simple to look throgh `/proc` and see if that process is still around.

Under other platforms you may need to play games with `ps` to check for the processes existence.