# Running a script in the background before logging in

Tags: linux

I have a python script that I want run prior to any user logging in. This is for a home automation server and I want it always to be up and running as soon as the system allows.

I already have it in the `rc.local` file including an ampersand. This works.

But I can't see the screen output that it produces.

When I log into the unit (it's a raspberry pi running raspian) via SSH I can start it using `screen` which works the best as when I logout and back in, it's still there. AND I can see the output from the script.

But when I try running `screen` from the `rc.local` file, and subsequently login to check, the script isn't there (ie `ps aux | grep script.py` confirms)

edit: I've taken on Nirk's solution below about using `tail`. From the command line, it works fine. But starting it form within `/etc/rc.local` doesn't. I have `touch`ed the file and everyone has write access to it.

This is what's in my `rc.local` file:

`python /home/pi/gateway.py &> /x10.log &`

**UPDATE**
This is how I did it in the end:

Although the question was just about how to run in the background prior to login, there was more to it. The script is a work in progress and because of the way a particular serial device acts with it, it is/was prone to crashing (I've almost got all the bugs out of it). I needed to be able to restart it as well. I tried `nohup` but for some reason, it wouldn't keep it alive so in the end I found the top answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696839/how-do-i-write-a-bash-script-to-restart-a-process-if-it-dies) page got it all sorted.

In my `/etc/rc.local` I included a shell script to run:

```
nohup /home/pi/alwaysrun.sh > /home/pi/mha.log 2>&1 &
```

`alwaysrun.sh` contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
until python /home/pi/gateway.py; do
    echo "'gateway.py' exited with exit code $?. Restarting..." >&2
    sleep 1
done
```

`nohup` will keep the `alwaysrun.sh` script alive, and that in turn keeps my `gateway.py` script running. The redirect of stdout and stderr means I can setup a tail (and/or go back and check) the log.

Comment: Why not just redirect the output to a log file and just tail that?

Comment: Thanks Nirk, I had thought of that, but the script provides a polling indicator to let me know its still alive, and although I haven't tried it, a tail would display a beeline for every dot that appears. `tail` would work for my finished script, but while I'm still building it, I need to see a live representation that its still running.

Comment: Perhaps running the script as you are doing from rc.local, but redirecting the output of the script to /dev/console?

Comment: Thanks guys, @nirk, you hit the nail on the head, tail DOES work as needed (I was expecting a newline at the end of each line, but it doesn't). So all I'm doing is redirecting stdout and stderr to a log, I can then tail the log perfectly. If you put that in as an answer I can tick it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using screen, if you just want to see the output you should redirect the output of the command to a log file and then tail the file.

Comment: Thanks Nirk, I know I said above that that worked, it did from the command line, but not from within `/etc/rc.local`. The log file is zero bytes. but the process appears to be running (in `ps aux`). Any final thoughts?

Comment: It may be run too early.  Can you post the script you are running (and whether it depends on a service like mysql)?