# Running python program after it is terminated via crontab

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, cron

I have a python webscraping program which needs to be scrapped continuously after the program is terminated. my technique is as follows

crontab -e (settings)

```
* * * * * /home/ahmed/Desktop/run.sh
```

run.sh

```
    TMP_FILE=/tmp/i_am_running
    [ -f $TMP_FILE ] && exit
    touch $TMP_FILE
    /usr/bin/python /home/ahmed/Desktop/python.py
    rm $TMP_FILE
```

The bash code must have some problem or may be my command in the crontab is wrong. the program is not running. Please guide

---

After Mark suggestions I modified the script like this

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=$PATH:/bin:/usr/bin

date +'%H:%M:%S Started' >> /home/ahmed/Desktop/log.txt

TMP_FILE=/tmp/i_am_running
[ -f $TMP_FILE ] && exit
touch $TMP_FILE

date +'%H:%M:%S Starting Python' >> /home/ahmed/Desktop/log.txt
/usr/bin/python /home/ahmed/Desktop/python.py
rm $TMP_FILE

date +'%H:%M:%S Ended' >> /home/ahmed/Desktop/log.txt
```

The cron command i am using is `* * * * * /home/ahmed/Desktop/run.sh`

the log file which is created is this

```
15:21:01 Started
15:21:02 Starting Python
15:22:02 Started
15:23:01 Started
15:24:01 Started
15:24:30 Ended
15:25:01 Started
15:25:01 Starting Python
15:26:01 Started
15:27:18 Started
15:28:01 Started
15:29:01 Started
15:30:01 Started
15:31:01 Started
15:31:16 Ended
15:32:01 Started
15:32:01 Starting Python
15:33:01 Started
15:34:01 Started
```

It seems like the program is restarted before its ended. the log file should have starting program, started, ended, starting program, started, ended and so on.

Can someone guide me please?

Comment: What is not running? The crontab? The script itself? Provide more details.

Comment: Use `logger` inside `run.sh`; perhaps start it with `#!/bin/bah -vx` for debugging purposes.

Comment: Typo I meant `#!/bin/bash -vx`

Comment: If you want to keep the Python script running even if it is crashed then you could use something like `supervisord` or create an upstart job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you made your script executable?

```
chmod +x /home/ahmed/Desktop/run.sh
```

Put a proper shebang and PATH in your script so it starts like this:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 PATH=$PATH:/bin:/usr/bin
```

Try your script on its own from the command line

```
/home/ahmed/Desktop/run.sh
```

If that doesn't work, change the shebang line to add `-xv` at the end

```
#!/bin/bash -xv
```

Check to see if /tmp/i_am_running exists

Check your cron log

```
grep CRON /var/log/syslog
```

Consider changing your script so you can see when it started and/or if it actually ran your python:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=$PATH:/bin:/usr/bin

date +'%H:%M:%S Started' >> /home/ahmed/Desktop/log.txt

TMP_FILE=/tmp/i_am_running
[ -f $TMP_FILE ] && exit
touch $TMP_FILE

date +'%H:%M:%S Starting Python' >> /home/ahmed/Desktop/log.txt
/usr/bin/python /home/ahmed/Desktop/python.py
rm $TMP_FILE

date +'%H:%M:%S Ended' >> /home/ahmed/Desktop/log.txt
```

By the way, I am not sure how running once at 18:01 constitutes "continuous scraping"?

Comment: i will change the timing to * * * * * . the timing was just for testing purpose. let me follow the steps you mentioned. thanks

Comment: I changed the code as u mentioned. and when i type grep CRON /var/log/syslog in the command line, it says binary file matches

Comment: "cd /var/log" and see if there is a cron.log or other logfile that your cron has been configured to use.

Comment: and i think the cron is working too because in the python its suppose to save data in the database and its saving. to be honest, i have no idea how the bash program is running and accomplishing the task. can you help me finding out how can i see log files. i want to learn the method please

Comment: Get the script running correctly first by checking the `log.txt` on your Desktop and seeing if the time is in there. Once the script works, then introduce it to cron.

Comment: its fetching data!! i am excited. my concern is that what if the python program crashes? and can i do this in the server so that the program runs continuously?

Comment: Have a look at the accepted answer for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/696839/how-do-i-write-a-bash-script-to-restart-a-process-if-it-dies

Comment: It seems like the program is restarted before its ended. the log file should have starting program, started, ended, starting program, started, ended and so on.

Comment: It looks correct. Sometimes cron starts the job before the last one has finished, so it says "Started" but then it doesn't say "Starting Python" because Python is already running and the script exits before it says "Starting Python".