# Best practice: Monitor processes

Tags: python, python-2.7

I was wondering what the best practice solution would be to constantly monitor and resart processes, because there are multiple ways in doing it.

Additional info:
I have a unix program which uses multiple processes to work. There's a main process, it always starts first and is not likely to die or terminate without stopping the program.

Then I spawn multiple "module" processes, which take care of some work and communicate through the main process. Those modules sometimes die because of exceptions, and because it's an external program I can't resolve the issues, so I have to restart them if they die.

I've made a program to check if any of the modules died and restart them, but I need to run it manually. My program checks if the pid files of the modules exist and if they listen on a specific tcp port. If the pid file doesn't exist or the socket can't establish connection, it restarts the module.

My thoughts so far:

- Cron job to run the checks every minute and restart any dead modules. (kind of an overkill, because they don't die that frequently)
- Daemon running in the background, which starts the modules and receives notifications if they die, so it doesn't have to check them constantly. (SIGCHLD signal, os.wait)

If I use the daemon method, how should I communicate with the daemon through my interface? (socket, or maybe a file which gets read if the daemon receives a specific signal)

Usually I would just go with the daemon because it seems to be the best practice method to restart the modules asap(cron only runs once a minute), but I've wanted to get some opinions from more experienced users. (I've never done something like this before, and asking doesn't hurt anyone :D)

I apologize if these questions are answered somewhere else, but I couldn't find any related question.

P.S. If I forgot something or you need more infos, please feel free to ask. :)

Comment: Possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/697064/190597

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would investigate running the monitoring process as part of a dedicated monitoring framework.   [Monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) is one example, however there are of course others.

This has the advantage of providing additional features which might be useful, such as email alerts and analytics.  In my experience, you should be able to use your existing program without too much modification, and [Monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) itself uses few system resources if that is a concern.