# nohup process automatically killed in Raspberry Pi machine

Tags: python, nohup

I have a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian OS.

After login via SSH, I ran a python script via nohup:

`nohup python3 start.py </dev/null >/dev/null &`

Then I logout. The python process was still running.

But after two days or several days, the python process was end. There is no error in log.

Can anyone give me some tips?

Comment: nohup is not a stable solution. Upgrade or reinstall linux which support systemd and use systemd service instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try redirecting `stderr` as well:

```
nohup python3 start.py </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Also I don't think this is really helpful but just add `disown` anyway:

```
nohup python3 start.py </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &
disown
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. The nohup solution is not robust. I following the answer and it works well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696839/how-do-i-write-a-bash-script-to-restart-a-process-if-it-dies/697064#697064

Comment: @comphilip `( python3 start.py & disown ) &>/dev/null </dev/null & disown` is enough. `nohup` is actually not needed. Also, the solution you [had](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696839/how-do-i-write-a-bash-script-to-restart-a-process-if-it-dies/697064#697064) already requires a process manager which is different from what you wanted to do here. I also personally use `screen -dmS name command` instead, so I could access the process back when I re-login, with `screen -r name`.