# Shell script: How to restart a process (with pipe) if it dies

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I currently use the technique described in [How do I write a bash script to restart a process if it dies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696839/how-do-i-write-a-bash-script-to-restart-a-process-if-it-dies) by [lhunath](https://stackoverflow.com/users/58803/lhunath) in order to restart a dead process.

```
until myserver; do
    echo "Server 'myserver' crashed with exit code $?.  Respawning.." >&2
    sleep 1
done
```

But rather than just invoking the process *myserver*, I would like to invoke such a thing:

```
 myserver 2>&1 | /usr/bin/logger -p local0.info &
```

How to use the first technique with a process with pipe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `until` loop itself can be piped into `logger`:

```
until myserver 2>&1; do
    echo "..."
    sleep 1
done | /usr/bin/logger -p local0.info &
```

since `myserver` inherits its standard output and error from the loop (which inherits from the shell).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `PIPESTATUS` variable to get the exit code from a specific command in a pipeline:

```
while :; do
    myserver 2>&1 | /usr/bin/logger -p local0.info
    if [[ ${PIPESTATUS[0]} != 0 ]]
    then echo "Server 'myserver' crashed with exit code ${PIPESTATUS[0]}.  Respawning.." >&2
         sleep 1
    else break
    fi
done
```

Comment: If we want to handle only the myserver failure (PIPESTATUS[0]), I think the chepner's answer is more elegant. If we want to handle the failure of /usr/bin/logger too, then your loop seams better.