# How do I write a bash script to restart a process if it exits gracefully?

Tags: bash

So I read this [How do I write a bash script to restart a process if it dies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696839/how-do-i-write-a-bash-script-to-restart-a-process-if-it-dies) and quickly discovered that this was not the dilemma I'm facing.

I copied the below into `/etc/init/` and it appears to be working.

```
description "Forever my process"

start on started mountall
stop on shutdown

respawn
respawn limit 5 5

script
    export HOME="/root"

    exec my_process >> /var/log/my-process.log 2>&1
end script
```

Comment: So what's the problem then?

Comment: The best answer is "don't" -- any modern OS will have a process supervision system built in that doesn't require rolling your own thing in bash. (On MacOS, this is launchd; on Fedora and other very new Linuxen it's supervisord; on Ubuntu it's upstart... and there are very strong competitors you can build/install for any UNIX like djb's daemontools and its BSD-licensed clone runit).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy that seems to be what's been posted. This is an upstart script so it will be system managed

Comment: Then again, what you're already doing _is_ "don't"; you're using... upstart, it looks like?

Comment: It's hardly a bash script doing the restarting, then, is it?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - that is the short answer for if it dies too, I'm trying to see if the wise have any better methods to immediately restart a process once it exits gracefully. below there is a method using sleep though that isn't exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: @ovatsug25, then that's a question about writing upstart configuration files, not about bash -- `upstart` can (and should!) be configured to do the restart itself, with the bash script embedded not changing at all from how it's already written.

Comment: And to add to that, as you have it that's exactly what will happen. The `respawn` keyword is for exactly your desired behaviour

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - I guess I learned what upstart is today then! thanks. would this be the 'modern OS process supervision system' you speak of? if it isn't, i'd gladly take a better answer or elaboration

Comment: Yes, upstart is one of the (many) available modern process supervision systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way:

```
while sleep 1; do 
    echo "success"
done
```

Seems to work fine for me.

Replace `sleep 1` with the command to start your process.

---

edit: this is an answer for the question in the title, I'm not sure what `/etc/init` or the code you gave has to do with the question

Comment: interesting. it does sleep though and I wanted to avoid that

Comment: No no, I used `sleep 1` as a test command (just because I wanted something that wouldn't exit immediately). In an actual script you would replace that with the real command you want to run.

Answer (score -3):

Given that this works, I'm posting this as an answer. If there is a better way to do it, please add.

```
description "Forever my process"

start on started mountall
stop on shutdown

respawn
# respawn limit 5 5 - use this if you want to limit it for any reason

script
    export HOME="/root"

    exec my_process >> /var/log/my-process.log 2>&1
end script
```

Comment: But this is also your question... I don't understand what the problem is?

Comment: Why do you have the `restart limit` directive, unless you genuinely want to limit the restart rate (in this case, no longer restarting if there are 5 failures inside a 5-second window)?