# http.listen() accept terminal commands while running

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following in my script:

```
var server = http.createServer(handleRequest);
server.listen(3000, function(err){
    console.log(err || 'Server listening on 3000');
});
```

When I execute the script in the terminal:

```
nodejs file.js
```

It runs in an endless loop until I hit <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd>. Is it possible to enter custom commands while the process is running since it doesn't go back to the default terminal? I would like to add a few custom commands to my app such as (but not limited to):

- stop
- reload
- restart

Comment: [Forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever) does that !

Comment: I have used the answer to  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/696839/how-do-i-write-a-bash-script-to-restart-a-process-if-it-dies to solve this problem.

Comment: I would like it to call functions within the script though, where reload reloads the configuration file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`process.stdin`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdin) stream (the `data` event is fired on newline):

```
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function (err, req, res) {
  // ...
});
server.listen(3000, function(err){
    console.log(err || 'Server listening on 3000');
});

var commands = {
  stop: function () {
    console.log('> stop');
  },
  start: function () {
    console.log('> start')
  },
  restart: function () {
    console.log('> restart')
  }
}

process.stdin.on('data', function (data) {
  data = (data + '').trim().toLowerCase();
  if (data in commands) {
    commands[data]();
  }
});
```

Just for reference [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemo) does something similar (it restarts the server when `rs` is entered [source](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/blob/master/lib/nodemon.js#L92-L101))

Comment: This looks like it is doing exactly what I am looking for!