# Redirect output to two files and restart the whole process if it dies

Tags: php, linux, bash, process

I have a PHP server that runs on my machine when I execute the following command :

```
php src/server.php > >(tee -a ./logs/logs.txt) 2> >(echo "$(date)"; tee -a ./logs/errors.log >&2)
```

If I did no mistake, it should runs the server, prompts all messages to the console and write them to ./logs/logs.txt and, separately, write error output to .logs/errors.log with a timestamp.

The command executes well in my console and starts the server while creating the logs files.

---

I am looking for a way to put this line in a (bash?) script so I can combine it with [this StackOverflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696839/how-do-i-write-a-bash-script-to-restart-a-process-if-it-dies) to restart the server if it crashes. For now, I've tried things like :

```
#!/bin/bash

php src/server.php >> >(echo "$(date)"; tee -a ./logs/logs.txt) 2>> >(echo "$(date)"; tee -a ./logs/errors.log >&2)
```

But it gives me the following error :

```
startServer.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `>'
startServer.sh: line 3: `php src/server.php >> >(echo "$(date)"; tee -a ./logs/logs.txt) 2>> >(echo "$(date)"; tee -a ./logs/errors.log >&2)'
```

I don't understand why it would not work as it runs perfectly when I run the command directly. It is a problem with the `#!bin/bash` code ? Or should I replace the `>>` with pipe (will it still works as expected ?) ?

---

Also, in the restart process solution, there is a `until myserver; do` line. What should I write instead of `myserver` ? `startServer` ?

Thanks everyone :)

**Edit:** Seems like `2> >(echo "$(date)"; tee -a ./logs/errors.log >&2)` do put the error message in errors.log but it does not print the date in the file before. :(

Comment: Whatever is running `startServer.sh` isn't using bash but is instead using `sh` (or some other shell). Also if you want to have this restarted when it dies I would, instead of using the loop idea, use a process/service supervisor (like systemd, runit, etc.)

Comment: Ho right. I always thought that "sh" was similar to "bash" (because of the sh in bash). I'll sleep smarter tonight ! When using `bash startServer.sh`it runs perfectly !

I'll take a look now at some process supervisor as you recommend. Thanks for your help!

Btw, I edited my message because I didn't manage to print a timestamp in my errors.log before appending the error message. Do you have an idea to make it works ?

Comment: You need to redirect the output of `date` to the log file too if you want that to work. And they are "similar" but "similar" is not "the same".