# Why isn't this command substitution returning the expected value?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm using a shell script from the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696839/how-do-i-write-a-bash-script-to-restart-a-process-if-it-dies) post to re-start a process if it exits. I have several processes that I need to start with this script, so I'm writing another script to launch them in order. I want to check that each process is launched successfully before continuing in the launch order. I've written a script similar to this.

```
#!/bin/sh

launch() {
    exec "$1" "$2" &!

    local pid="$(pidof $2)"
    echo "PID: $pid"

    if [ "$pid" == "" ]; do
            return 1
    done

    return 0
}

launch [looping-script.sh] [process-to-wrap]

exit 0
```

When I run this script with valid arguments for `launch` the script and process start and show up in `ps` output, but the value of `$pid` is blank and the function return `1`. However, if I take the `[looping-script.sh]` argument out of the equation, like so.

```
#!/bin/sh

launch() {
    exec "$1" &!

    local pid="$(pidof $1)"
    echo "PID: $pid"

    if [ "$pid" == "" ]; do
            return 1
    done

    return 0
}

launch [process-to-wrap]

exit 0
```

Then `$pid` matches the value output by `ps` for the process and the function returns `0`. Is there something incorrect about my call in the first script?

`bash --version` output if it's useful:

```
GNU bash, version 4.3.30(1)-release (arm-petalinux-linux-gnueabi)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
```

Comment: What does `&!` mean? I've never seen that, and can't find it in the Bash manual.

Comment: `pidof` may be running before the wrapper script has had time to start the process to wrap. Try adding `sleep 1` after you run the looping script.

Comment: @Bamar I think that's it. I was way too deep into that thinking it was something weird about the exec command and the script I was using. If you want to post that as an answer, it's all yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not allowing time for `looping-script.sh` to start `process-to-wrap`. Try adding a `sleep` command before checking for the PID.

```
exec "$1" "$2" &!
sleep 1
local pid="$(pidof $2)"
```

Answer (score 2):

Why use `pidof` to get the process ID of the monitored command? It will not do what you want if there happens to be more than one matching process.  *The shell can tell you* what the PID was of the last subshell it started, e.g. to run a background pipeline:

```
exec "$@" &
local pid=$!
echo "PID: $pid"
```

Note also the `"$@"`, which accommodates any number of arguments to the command you want to launch.

Comment: By the way, I can't speak for yours, but my `bash` doesn't like the `!` appended to the `&`.

Comment: @Barmar answered my specific question so I'm giving him the checkmark but I'll look into using `$!` for the process ID. I have other guards in place to prevent more than one instance of the process from running but thanks for the concern. The script above was more for illustration and isn't the actual production script.

Comment: Using `$!` in my case returns the PID of the `looping-script.sh` argument and not the PID of the `process-to-wrap` argument. That won't work for me, as I'm trying to ensure that the wrapped process is running before moving on.