# How to check whether or not a python script is up?

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x

I want to make sure my python script is always running, 24/7. It's on a Linux server. If the script crashes I'll restart it via cron.

Is there any way to check whether or not it's running?

Comment: Why do not use supervisord ?

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with, as Benjamin put it, "hacking this with a script", particularly if you are on a hand-rolled/light/embedded distro, but if you're on something mainstream, its best to learn existing facilities for the job.  Which is probably systemd almost anywhere you go on an up-to-date distro, and about 5 different possibilities if an older distro needs to be supported.  Also, this is more a superuser.com oriented question.

Answer (score 3):

Taken from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/697064/1337398):

A bash script which starts your python script and restarts it if it didn't exit normally :

```
#!/bin/bash
until script.py; do
    echo "'script.py' exited with code $?. Restarting..." >&2
    sleep 1
done
```

Then just start the monitor script in background:

```
nohup script_monitor.sh &
```

---

**Edit** for multiple scripts:

**Monitor script:**

```
cat script_monitor.sh
#!/bin/bash

until ./script1.py 
do
    echo "'script1.py' exited with code $?. Restarting..." >&2
    sleep 1
done &

until ./script2.py 
do
    echo "'script2.py' exited with code $?. Restarting..." >&2
    sleep 1
done &
```

**scripts example:**

```
cat script1.py
#!/usr/bin/python
import time
while True:
    print 'script1 running'
    time.sleep(3)

cat script2.py
#!/usr/bin/python
import time
while True:
    print 'script2 running'
    time.sleep(3)
```

Then start the monitor script:

```
./script_monitor.sh
```

This starts one monitor script per python script in the background.

Comment: 1) and if I needed to monitory 3 python scripts, how would I do that?

Comment: 2) does my python script have to return any value so that the "sh" script will be able to recognize that the python script has crashed?

Answer (score 1):

Try this and enter your script name.

`ps aux | grep SCRIPT_NAME`

Answer (score 1):

- Create a script (say `check_process.sh`) which will

  - Find the process id for your python script by using `ps` command.
    Save it in a variable say `pid`
  - Create an infinite loop. Inside it, search for your process. If found then sleep for 30 or 60 seconds and check again.
  - If `pid` not found, then exit the loop and send mail to your `mail_id` saying that process is not running.

Now call  `check_process.sh` by a `nohup` so it will run in background continuously.

I implemented it way back and remember it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

- runit
- supervisor
- monit
- systemd (i think)

Do not hack this with a script

Answer (score 1):

[upstart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upstart), on Ubuntu, will monitor your process and restart it if it crashes.  I believe [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) will do that too.  No need to reinvent this.