# How to write a bash script that runs a python program that restarts with parameters

Tags: python, bash, parameters

I've written a bash script based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696839/how-do-i-write-a-bash-script-to-restart-a-process-if-it-dies/697064#697064) and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/461546/run-a-python-script-in-background-and-restart-it-on-crash). The script is:

```
#!/bin/bash 
until python data.py $1 $2 ; do
    echo "'data.py' crashed with exit code $?. Restarting..." >> errors.txt
    sleep 1
done
```

I run it:

```
./run.sh ‘a’ ‘n’
```

but in data.py

```
if sys.argv[1] == 'a':
```

returns false.
How do I pass $1 and $2 to my Python program? TIA!!!

EDIT: SOLUTION

Thanks to Jandom and andlrc:
I call it:

```
./run.sh "a" "n"
```

and change the script to:

```
until python data.py "$@" ; do
```

Comment: Are these really `‘` (i.e. [`u'\u2018'`](http://www.charbase.com/2018-unicode-left-single-quotation-mark))? Because then, `sys.argv == [script_name, '‘a‘', '‘b‘']`, probably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending special quotes to your shell script:

```
% charinfo ‘’
U+2018 SINGLE TURNED COMMA QUOTATION MARK [Pi]
U+2019 SINGLE COMMA QUOTATION MARK [Pf]
```

Run it with single or double quotes:

```
./run.sh "a" "b"
```

Also remember quotes in your bash script or `$1` and `$2` will undergo word splitting:

```
#!/bin/bash
until python data.py "$1" "$2"; do
    echo "'data.py' crashed with exit code $?. Restarting..." >> errors.txt
    sleep 1
done
```

As pointed out before you can use `"$@"` which will refer to all arguments send to your bash script.

Comment: Sorry I think on hindsight I should have accepted this answer.

Comment: @schoon You can always change the accepted answer. But I don't mind leaving the accepted to Janom.

Answer (score 3):

script.sh (make sure it allow execute)

```
#!/bin/sh
python script.py "$@"
```

script.py (first param is ./script.sh if run as ./script.sh from terminal), so, script.py:

```
import sys
print(sys.argv[1:])
# sys.argv[1] == a, sys.argv[2] == b, etc..
```