# Python script stopping after changes to computer security

Tags: python

I have a python script I use at work that checks the contents of a webpage and reports to me the changes.  It used to run fine checking the site every 5 minutes and then our company switched some security software.  The script will still run but will stop after an hour or so. Its not consistent, it will sometimes be a few hours but about an hour seems average.  There are no errors raised that are reported in the shell.  Is there a way to have this re-started automatically?  The code is below, it used to just call the function and then a sleep command, but I added the for loop and the print line for debugging to see what time it is stopping.

```
import time
import datetime
import txtWip

while True:
    txtWip.main()
    for i in range(1, 300,100):
        current_time = time.strftime(r"%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S", time.localtime())
        print(current_time)
        time.sleep(100)
```

Comment: If the script runs successfully for first time and fails after a while, I would suggest you to configure a [cron job](http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html). It is easy to manage.

Comment: I would strongly recommend that you use a scheduler for running scripts rather than have it sleep between executions.

Comment: ok, thanks.  I will look into those.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is for your program to run as a daemon[1]: a background process that no longer responds to ordinary SIGKILL or even SIGHUP. You also want this daemon to restart itself on termination - effectively making it run forever.

Rather than write your own daemon script, it's far easier to do one of the following:

- **If on Linux, use [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/).**

  This is a replacement for the `init.d` daemon that supervises all processes while your machine running. It is capable of respawning a process in the event of an unexpected crash - see [an example here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/251577/how-to-supervise-and-automatically-restart-a-process), and a [Python-specific example here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175751/how-do-i-run-a-python-script-in-the-background-and-restart-it-after-a-crash). It is the gold standard for such tasks on this platform.

  For certain Ubuntu releases, `systemd` is the prodigal son and should be used instead.

  An alternative with an [external bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696839/how-do-i-write-a-bash-script-to-restart-a-process-if-it-dies) that doesn't require messing around with `upstart` is also a possibility.
- **If on Windows, use [ReStartMe](http://www.howtogeek.com/130665/quickly-and-automatically-restart-a-windows-program-when-it-crashes/)**
- **If on Mac, install and configure [runit](http://kchard.github.io/runit-quickstart/) appropriately**

---

[1] *The following is not cross-platform advice*. You may or may not actually need to run this as [a true daemon](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56495/whats-the-difference-between-running-a-program-as-a-daemon-and-forking-it-into). A simple background job (i.e. invoked by appending an `&` when you run `python <file_name>.py` to the end) should be sufficient - this will quit when the terminal you ran it in quits, but you can get around this by using the Linux utility `screen`.