# crontab to run python file if not running already

Tags: python, cron

I want to execute my python file via crontab only if its down or not running already. I tried adding below entry in cron tab but it does not work

```
24 07 * * * pgrep -f test.py || nohup python /home/dp/script/test.py & > /var/tmp/test.out
```

test.py works fine if i run  `pgrep -f test.py || nohup python /home/dp/script/test.py & > /var/tmp/test.out` manually and it also works in crontab if i remove pgrep -f test.py || from my crontab and just keep `24 07 * * * nohup python /home/dp/script/test.py & > /var/tmp/test.out`

Any idea why crontab does not work if i add pgrep -f? is there any other way i can run test.py just one time to avoid multiple running processes of test.py?
Thanks,
Deepak

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I write a bash script to restart a process if it dies?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/696839/how-do-i-write-a-bash-script-to-restart-a-process-if-it-dies)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### pgrep -f lists itself as a false match when run from cron

I did the test with a `script.py` running an infinite loop. Then

```sh
pgrep -f script.py
```

...from the terminal, gave ***one*** pid, `13132` , while running from cron:

```sh
pgrep -f script.py > /path/to/out.txt
```

outputs ***two*** pids, `13132` and `13635`.

We can therefore conclude that the command `pgrep -f script.py` lists itself as a match, when run from cron. Not sure how and why, but most likely, this is indirectly caused by the fact that `cron` runs with a quite limited set of environment variables (HOME, LOGNAME, and SHELL).

#### The solution

Running `pgrep -f` from a (wrapper) script makes the command *not* list itself, even when run from `cron`. Subsequently, run the wrapper from `cron`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

if ! pgrep -f 'test.py'
then
    nohup python /home/dp/script/test.py & > /var/tmp/test.out
# run the test, remove the two lines below afterwards
else
    echo "running" > ~/out_test.txt
fi
```

Comment: `if [ -z $(command) ]` is usually an antipattern for `if command`, provided `command` is correctly written.

Comment: @tripleee not sure what you mean, `if [ -z "$(pgrep -f 'test.py')" ]` is a valid test.

Comment: It is not incorrect, but it is highly dubious stylistically.  The reason commands produce an exit code is so that you can use them in `if` or `while` condition.

Comment: @triplee thanks for mentioning, that is new to me but makes sense. Fixed now.

Comment: The second `pgrep` inside the `if` seems superfluous, too.

Comment: @tripleee Ah, you're right of course, blindly copied OP's command, fixed.Thanks once again.

Comment: Thanks all for the great comments and helping me with the options.

Comment: great solution !!

Answer (score 3):

It is generally a good idea to check whether the application is running or not within the application rather than checking from outside and starting it. Managing the process within the process rather than expecting another process to do it.

1. Let the cron run the application always
2. At the start of execution of the application, have a lock file or similar mechanism that will tell whether the process is already running or not.
3. If the application is already running, update somewhere the last test time and break the new process.
4. If the application is not running, log somewhere and notify someone (if required) and trigger the process start.

This will ensure that you will have more control over the life time of a process AND let you decide what to do in case of failures.

Not to mention, if you want to make sure that the application up time is to be high, it is best to make use of monitoring services such as [Monit](https://linux.die.net/man/1/monit). Again this will depend on your application to add a sanity layer that says whether it is OK or not.

Answer (score 1):

cron may be seeing the `pgrep -f test.py` process as well as the `test.py` process, giving you the wrong result from `pgrep`.
Try the command without the `-f`, this should just look for an occurrence of `test.py` or replace `-f` with `-o` which will look for the oldest occurrence.

Your other option is to insert into test.py something along the lines of:

```
Pid = os.popen('pgrep -f test.py').read(5).strip()
```

which will allow you to check within the code itself, if it is already running.

Answer (score 1):

Came across this old question looking for solution myself.

Use [psutil](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil):

```
import psutil
import sys
from subprocess import Popen

for process in psutil.process_iter():
    if process.cmdline() == ['python', 'your_script.py']:
        sys.exit('Process found: exiting.')

print('Process not found: starting it.')
Popen(['python', 'your_script.py'])
```

You can also use start time of the previous process to determine if it's running too long and might be hung:

```
process.create_time()
```

There is tons of other useful metadata of the process.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `pgreg -f` is recognizing the shell script that cron uses to run the command itself.

I solved the `pgrep -f` problem by encoding the file name in rot13 and decoding it with a python one-liner, since I didn't want to add a script wrapper just for the cron job. i.e.:

```
pgrep -f $(python3 -c 'import codecs; print(codecs.decode("grfg.cl", "rot13"))') || nohup python /home/dp/script/test.py & > /var/tmp/test.out
```

Added: You can use tr to decode rot13 which would result in a shorter and easier to read command:

```
pgrep -f $(echo grfg.cl | tr a-zA-Z n-za-mN-ZA-M) || nohup python /home/dp/script/test.py & > /var/tmp/test.out
```

Answer (score 0):

Why just check pid is already running like this

```
Pid = os.popen('pgrep -f myscript.py').readlines()
if len(Pid) > 1:
 exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a test file by the name test.py
If you try executing the same file again it should quit.

```
import time
import os
from tempfile import TemporaryFile
import subprocess


def cron_running(p_name):
    run_cnt=0
    with TemporaryFile() as tf:
        subprocess.call(["ps","ax"], stdout=tf)
        tf.seek(0)
        for line in tf:
            if p_name in line.decode('ascii'):
                run_cnt+=1
    if run_cnt > 1:
        quit()

if cron_running(os.path.basename(__file__)):
    print("cron is already running")
    quit()

for i in range(60):
    time.sleep(1)
```