# automatically restart a linux process if it fails or crash

Tags: linux, bash, process, scripting

I have a linuxOS based system.i want to restart a executable bin file if it killed or crashed.

location of executable file in home/bin/filename
i have etc directory where i init.d ,systemd,cron sun-directories are there.

please suggest any script to write so that if the bin file will be restarted if it srashes.

Comment: What did you try? did you go through basic `bash` loop controls? Can we see some code that you have tried?

Comment: See: [How do I write a bash script to restart a process if it dies?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/696839/3776858)

Comment: Hi Inian , i didnt find any solution yet ,can you plz provides some bash script ,so i can try

Comment: @bkb: Refer the comments above for similar questions and use the accepted answer(the one with a tick mark)

Answer (score 1):

Try `restartd` package.

> Restartd is a daemon for checking running and not running processes.
>   It reads the /proc directory every n seconds and does a POSIX regexp
>   on the process names. You can execute a script or a program if the
>   process is or is not running.

You can set what process to watch, The interval, and  etc.