# Forking, daemonizing and monitoring a python script

Tags: python, linux, daemon

I have a python script sc.py on my debian server.

I would like :

- To run it as a daemon and keep it running indefinitely
- To run it N times (as sub processes, children, forks) in //
- To monitor the whole processes (in order to restart any dying process)

Do you know software that would enable me to do so?

I don't know if I have to look for a solution on the python side (any python module or configuration) or if there is a debian package somewhere which does that job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`supervisord`](http://supervisord.org/) for this.

It daemonizes Python processes for you, and also handles subprocesses.

Comment: Thanks for helping. Do you know if there is the same kind of tool that works with any kind of script (such as bash) ?

Comment: supervisord should work with anything you can execute, not just Python. It is itself written in Python though.

Comment: Yes, that's what I figured out and I went for this solution that perfectly matches my needs. Thanks again. ;)

Answer (score 1):

If this is a one-time task (that is, you are not creating a software product) I would quick-and-dirty use a combination of shell scripting and a terminal multiplexer like [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/). For restarting processes that died (that is, they emitted an exit code other than `0`), just [use the shell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/697064/1181063).

Start your processes for example like this:

```
for i in n/*; do
    screen -d -m -L -S $i -t $i until python sc.py $i; do echo "Crashed with exit code $?.  Respawning.." >&2 ; sleep 1 ; done
done
```

This would

- Create a new screen session for every file in the subdirectory `n/` running your script,
- Restart your python script unless it exited successfully (using Bash's [`until`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/697064/1181063))
- Set the title (`-t`) and session name (`-S`) to the input file name,
- And turn on logging of all the output for later inspection if something went wrong (`-L`).

You can then use normal screen commands like `screen -list` to list all running tasks and `screen -r <session name>` to view the running session output.

Comment: Thanks for the consideration and the time spent. I need my script run as a service from boot to shutdown, and during its whole life, it will process requests as they arrive. Do you think screen is the solution?

Comment: @Antho Welcome! No, I advise against screen then. I read some people actually use setups like this in production *cough cough*, but I would recommend against running this non-interactively. zmbq's answer (supervisord) is better suited in that case.

Comment: So we agreed... I did forget about screen, thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 1):

Another process manager I stumbled upon is [`circus`](https://circus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

It looks more adventurous, if that's your thing ;)

And the web interface is richer than supervisord's: See some nice [screenshots](http://circus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/for-ops/circusweb/#circushttpd).

Comment: Looks a bit more complex but it may help someday if my needs change. Thanks for the followup :)