# Restart code within itself

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, restart

I had to start coding on `python` without any education in coding. So my skill is shame. 
I have a `telegram bot`. Sometimes it crashes, I don't know why and actually it doesn't matter, but I need to make bot restart itself when it crashes because of some weird loss of data. So please explain me how to add `while True` or `try-except`. Please, teach me where should I put these constructions in my code. All the code has to be inside `try statement`, am I right? I am really sorry for dumb questions, but I need your help. Thank you!

Comment: You'd be best off reading a tutorial or two. And you should fix the underlying problem rather than restarting on failure.

Comment: This is not a personalized on demand tutorial site. Just go read existing tutorials first and come back if you have a specific question that is not already addressed elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using linux, then you could write an independent bash script that would restart your python script in case of crashes and keep it running:

```
until foo.py; do
    echo "'foo.py' crashed with exit code $?.  Respawning.." >&2
    sleep 1
done
```

You will want to run this bash script in the background:

```
nohup ./bar.sh &
```

([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696839/how-do-i-write-a-bash-script-to-restart-a-process-if-it-dies/697064#697064))

Answer (score -1):

Going off [Python: about catching ANY exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990718/python-about-catching-any-exception)

You could do something like the following:

```
while (true):
    try:
        #your code here
    except:
       print "Caught an exception, discarding it."
```

Note that this catches ANY exception, which isn't a good idea.

Comment: YOU'RE MY HERO! THANK YOU!