# Send notification when Apache Solr service goes down

Tags: php, apache, solr, drupal-7, pecl

I'am using Apache Solr 3.6.2 integrated with Drupal 7.*. Sometimes Apache solr service goes down, and I am completely clueless that Solr is down. I don't have any other choice than manually login to the Linux server and start solr.

Is there any PHP library or piece of code that I can write so that whenever Solr service is down, it will notify me by triggering email (using php) or it will automatically restart apache solr. I am looking for some PHP PECL.

Is there a better way than PECL? Let me know if it is possible? If possible, How can I implement this in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

There are *many* ways to monitor a service under Linux.

Look at [Nagios](https://www.nagios.org/), [Icinga](https://www.icinga.com/), [netdata](https://my-netdata.io/) or any of the commercial options available (such as Pagerduty).

If you have installed Solr as a proper service on your system (i.e. as a SystemV/Upstart/systemd service), that service daemon can also restart the service if it disappears for you. How you do this depends on your configuration.

If you're handling it manually, you can [also write a small bash script that restarts the process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696839/how-do-i-write-a-bash-script-to-restart-a-process-if-it-dies) and waits until it disappears, before restarting it again.