# programmatically detect a crash of a program on MacOS?

Tags: bash, macos, crash, operating-system, fault

I've got a program I didn't write; another department in our company did. Suppose the executable is called Snafu. I need to be able to run it unattended and detect if it crashed. This may happen 1 millisecond after launch, or 1 hour after launch. The program is a black box and it won't tell me or give me a hint that it has crashed. I don't have its PID either. Other than grepping the output of ps (let's say I want to run several Snafu instances at once), how can I detect the crash of one instance of Snafu? I will launch it from a BASH script.

Comment: This question has a very good answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696839/how-do-i-write-a-bash-script-to-restart-a-process-if-it-dies

Comment: Oh.. solve the halting problem?

Comment: The question does not mention infinite loops, so I don't think they're getting tripped up by the halting problem. Detecting crashes seems like a very reasonable and doable thing.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a lot on how it crashes.

- will it stop, ie. exit
- will it hang
- will it trash
- etc.

Going from the complete black-box approach, you will never know when the application crashes, and therefore it is impossible to react to it.

For the remainder, I will assume that `snafu` exits.

The, more or less, traditional way of doing it is:

```
#!/bin/bash
snafu 1 &
snaf1=$!
snafu 2 &
snaf2=$!
while : ; do
    sleep 1
    if [ ps $snaf1 ] ; then
        echo "snafu 1 still runs"
    else
        echo "snafu 1 died "
        snafu 1 &
        snafu1=$!
    fi
    #same if for snafu 2
 done
```

See the remark from Luis Muñoz for the use of PID, ps etc; but still many people are doing this. Also: if you start `snafu` from a shell script, you will have its PID.

Another approach would be:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -o monitor
trap what_when_died SIGCHLD
what_when_died(){
    #actions to do when a snafu dies
}


snafu 1 &
snafu 2 &

sleep inf
```

There are some behaviour aspects that you need to consider; `set -o monitor` will make the shell pass SIGINT to the children instead of reacting to it etc.

Comment: I tried the trap approach. That didn't work for some reason. The program I'm testing I think launches another program.