# log every exception using tee for a respawning bash script

Tags: bash

I want to execute a respawning `bash script` which looks like the following

```
until python3 myapp.py; do
  echo "$(date) -- every exeception" | tee -a /var/log/app.log
  sleep 1;
done
```

This is basically [respawning the script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696839/how-do-i-write-a-bash-script-to-restart-a-process-if-it-dies) if it dies.

In the example of the link it only logs the `$?` which might just be a number. But I wish to `tee` the exceptions that occur when the script fails to the `log/app.log` file.

I tried different stuff but nothing works. Any direction how I can get the exceptions logged in the above mentioned way.

### trial

```
until python3 myapp.py; do
    echo "$(date) > &2 >&1 | tee -a /var/log/app.log
    sleep 1;
done
```

Output from log file

```
Fri May 18 18:09:03 UTC 2018 > 2>&1
Fri May 18 18:09:03 UTC 2018 > 2>&1
Fri May 18 18:09:04 UTC 2018 > 2>&1
Fri May 18 18:09:05 UTC 2018 > 2>&1
Fri May 18 18:09:06 UTC 2018 > 2>&1
Fri May 18 18:09:06 UTC 2018 > 2>&1
Fri May 18 18:09:07 UTC 2018 > 2>&1
Fri May 18 18:09:29 UTC 2018 >&2>&1
Fri May 18 18:09:30 UTC 2018 >&2>&1
Fri May 18 18:09:30 UTC 2018 >&2>&1
Fri May 18 18:09:31 UTC 2018 >&2>&1
Fri May 18 18:09:32 UTC 2018 >&2>&1
Fri May 18 18:09:33 UTC 2018 >&2>&1
```

Comment: Put the `| tee -a ...` after the `done`. You might need `done 2>&1 | tee -a` if the exception is written to stderr.

Comment: ...right now, you're only `tee`ing the `echo`, not the `python3 myapp.py` call.

Comment: Another option is `until python3 myapp.py > >(tee -a /var/log/app.log) 2>&1; do ...` -- the point of using a process substitution instead of a regular pipeline there is to avoid disrupting the exit status (as unless the `pipefail` runtime flag is set, the exit status of a pipeline is that of its last component).

Comment: I tried `until python3 app.py; do
 sleep 1;
done 2>&1 | tee -a /var/log/app.log` but the script didn't respawn

Comment: Can you provide a reproducer for that? If I run `stub() ( sleep 3; exit 1; ); until stub; do sleep 1; echo "respawning"; done 2>&1 | tee -a stub-test.log`, it respawns just fine. An issue we can't see ourselves without your `app.py` is an issue nobody can check their answers for.

Comment: (BTW, what's your operating system? The better practice is to use whatever process supervision system is supported by your OS vendor -- systemd, upstart, launchd, etc -- to do the respawning; when that's done correctly, you have a chain of processes that each check their childrens' status and recover from failures all the way back to PID 1).

Comment: I actually am using a custom yocto image with `linux-mainline` kernel on a board for embedded application. Sadly there is no `cron` available but I can perhaps create a `systemd` script. If the code crashes will `systemd` restart it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Yocto -- if your OS vendor doesn't already set up/support systemd, it's probably better to use a simpler init system -- personally, I'm very fond of [Runit](http://smarden.org/runit/). Either *will* indeed restart your service for you (if configured to do so); see http://smarden.org/runit/runscripts.html to see just how simple a runit script is.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy went ahead and changed the whole outlook of the problem with a long but working solution. Care having a look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a `logging` handler for the application I have and decided to use the `until` loop into a `tmux` session. The Session is created using a `systemd` service (hinted by @CharlesDuffy)

Session creator `bash` script:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 1;

/usr/bin/tmux new-session -d -s test
/usr/bin/tmux set-option set-remain-on-exit on

/usr/bin/tmux new-window -d -n 'testpy' -t test:1 'sleep 1; until usr/bin/python3 /home/root/test/test.py; do echo $(date) 2>&1; sleep 1; done'
```

gave it executable rights`chmod +x testsess`

Created a `systemd` script in the `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.wants/testpy.service`

`testpy.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=test service
After=influxdb.service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/root/test/testsess
ExecStop=/usr/bin/tmux kill-session -t test
RemainAfterExit=true
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

(not a `systemd` champ here! but the script works)

reloaded the daemon

`systemctl daemon-reload`

and started the service

`systemctl start testpy.service`

### Checks

`tmux ls`

should create a `test` session and in window nr. 1 the script respawns even on failure.

Comment: Personally, I would have skipped the use of tmux here -- it provides an indirection layer that makes systemd's ability to tell if the process under supervision is active less accurate, and prevents output from being logged through journald as is default for other services -- but this does generally look workable, even so.