# Get output of server crash from server re-spawning script

Tags: bash, logging, process, restart

I currently have [Homebridge](https://github.com/nfarina/homebridge) set up on my raspberry pi. When the pi boots, it starts a script which attempts to keep homebridge alive. I originally took the script from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696839/how-do-i-write-a-bash-script-to-restart-a-process-if-it-dies) answer which walks you through the rather trivial process of creating such a script. However, I have slightly adapted the script and it now looks like this:

```
until "homebridge" -s /bin/sh pi; do
    echo "Server homebridge crashed with exit code $?.  Respawning.." >&2
    echo "Looks like Homebridge just crashed, restarting it now..." | mail -s "Homebridge Crash" pi
    rm -r /home/pi/.homebridge/accessories/cachedAccessories
    sleep 1
done
```

It is virtually the same as the original script with the exception that it deletes a folder and waits a second before re-spawning. Furthermore, it sends some mail to my user (`pi`) to let me know that the process has died and that it is re-spawning. This has been working perfectly for me with the simple omission of any sort of de-bugging. By that I mean that whilst I do get notified that the process has died, I am not presented with an output of the process when it died. It would be perfect if the mail could include, for example, the last 300 lines before the process exited in order to aid with debugging following a crash

What exactly would I need to add to the above script in order to receive a 'log' of what the `homebridge` output was just before it crashed in order to help with debugging?

Thank you in advance for your help,

Kind regards, Rocco